# É possível receber notificações de perguntas específicas?

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso, status-pronto, notificações

Existe alguma forma de receber notificações sempre que houver alterações (basicamente novas respostas e comentários tanto na pergunta quanto nas respostas) em determinadas perguntas que não são de sua autoria?

Pensei que marcar como favorita pudesse fazer isso, mas pelo que entendi [desta pergunta no meta do SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), as notificações de favoritos serão implementadas futuramente. Isso significa que, atualmente, apenas quem fez a pergunta pode receber notificações de alterações?

Muitas vezes eu comento em perguntas para ajudar quando eu não tenho uma resposta completa, e gostaria de acompanhar estas perguntas para saber o desfecho. Se eu marcar a pergunta como favorita (ou salvar o link), eu teria que ficar revisitando periodicamente uma lista crescente de perguntas ou esperar que alguém me marque em um comentário.

**Atualização**: toda pergunta tem um feed RSS associado, com um link exibido no canto inferior direito da página. No entanto, através deste feed, só é possível acompanhar a inclusão de novas respostas, mas não comentários nem edições da pergunta, das respostas ou dos comentários.

Comment: Não existe hoje. Acho interessante, entretanto pode ir contra alguma política de privacidade, pois você pode virar um belo de um stalker! Fora isso, acho que você poderia colocar a tag `novo-recurso` na sua pergunta.

Comment: @Math Dei uma olhada na [política de privacidade do SE](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), mas não encontrei nada que fosse contra esse tipo de notificação. Parece que a política se aplica à divulgação de dados pessoais, que acho que não tem a ver com o que estou sugerindo.

Answer (score 12):

A [**API**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) do Stack Exchange está aí pra essas coisas. E não precisa nem criar uma App, plugin ou extensão, é só pesquisar no [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) que provavelmente alguém já fez algo do gênero.

E, efetivamente <sup><sub><sub>não testei, porém</sub></sub></sup> :

> ## [StackEye](https://stackapps.com/q/4454/10590)
>
> ### [Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on Stack Exchange sites](https://stackapps.com/q/4454/10590)
>
> *StackEye is a Chrome extension which can be used to follow other users for their answers and questions. Using StackEye you can also add a question to your watchlist there by getting notifications for each answer/comment on it.*
>
> **Followed Users will display notifications in extension's popup window.**
>
> [image]
>
> **A list of watched questions is also available; questions can be unwatched in bulk from this screen.**
>
> [image]

Comment: Você já testou se funciona com o SOpt?

Comment: Não instalei, não... e foi o primeiro que achei buscando "follow questions"... pode ser que haja outros.

Comment: @brasofilo, para quem mais se interessar, o plugin StackEye para o Google Chrome já está disponível para ser usado com o ***SOpt*** também. O criador do plugin liberou a versão 2.2 tornando isso possível. Grato!

Comment: @bigown, plugin StackEye para o Google Chorme já disponível para o SOpt.

Answer (score 9):

De fato, parece que não há como receber notificações nesse caso, mas se o problema for ficar revisitando uma lista de perguntas, a própria aba "Favoritos" já te ajuda bastante. Veja essas capturas de tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No SOpt eu tenho 2 favoritos, e nenhum deles foi mexido desde a última vez que olhei. O título da aba está normal. No SOen eu tenho 81 favoritos, e 35 deles foram alterados. Quais? Aqueles que estão com o *background* amarelado.

A única desvantagem desse método é que você tem que abrir imediatamente todas as perguntas alteradas, pois se você mudar de página e voltar essa marcação terá sumido, e você não saberá mais o que foi modificado e o que não foi (a propósito, eu acabei de fazer isso agora... d'oh!).

Não sei se isso cobre todo tipo de alteração ou não, mas *me parece* que não está limitado somente a novas respostas, como o feed RSS. Mesmo porque eu acompanho várias perguntas fechadas, como deu pra ver, e ele continuou me notificando (inclusive, a terceira da lista foi excluída faz uma semana, e eu ainda fui notificado). Se bem que faz tanto tempo que não revisito essa lista (estou inativo no SOen faz mais de 1 ano) que não sei se as perguntas já estavam fechadas ou não.

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar usar isso e ver se me atende! O +1 fica pra amanhã, já atingi o limite de hoje. =P

Comment: Pô, @Dang, você atingiu o limite no Meta? Legal isso!

Comment: @brasofilo Não foi tanto trabalho, eu só votei em vários tópicos que acho que deveriam fazer parte. =P O sistema chegou a reclamar que eu não dava upvote em perguntas há muito tempo. rs

Answer (score 7):

Eu estava fuçando minha página de perfil e na seção **Preferências** encontrei *Gerenciar e-mails de perguntas filtradas*.

Como soava relacionado com essa questão, fui dar uma olhada e me pediu login na Stack Exchange, ou seja, é um único recurso global.

Nada do que estarei relatando aqui foi testado pois eu estou quase sempre checando as novas perguntas, mas faz bastante sentido.

Na página que se abre, mesmo que esteja em inglês, não é difícil de se imaginar o que se deve fazer.

É de se supor que por exemplo setássemos **php** em *I'd like to include...* e *Stack Overflow em Port* no campo **on...** a cada 15 minutos (terceiro item) nós receberíamos um boletim com todas as novas perguntas de PHP, se alguma, nesse intervalo de tempo.

Porém setar o SOPT como site se faz por marcar um *checkbox* e quando feito o URL do SOPT **não vai** para o campo de texto logo acima o que me faz imaginar que qualquer URL da Stack Exchange possa ser definida ali, inclusive uma pergunta específica.

Candidatos ao crash-test são bem-vindos. :p

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta é antiga, bem como as respostas/comentários, mas gostaria de deixar registrado uma atualização.

Instalei hoje o [StackEye](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/stackeye?hl=pt-BR) no Chrome e achei muito funcional e útil. Ele cria um ícone nas perguntas e nos perfis de usuários que podem ser clicados para você segui-los (vide imagem):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem como mostra notificações do que você está seguindo no ícone da extensão no Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei bastante interessante e útil.