# Posso colocar uma tag na pergunta por causa de uma resposta?

Tags: debate, tags, respostas

Algumas vezes, *depois* que uma pergunta foi respondida, notamos que tem uma tag que encaixa bem no assunto, justamente por causa da resposta.

Será que isso é uma promoção indevida da resposta ou é um motivo válido para catalogação do conteúdo? Desde que caiba no limite de 5 tags ou dê para trocar alguma sem maiores problemas.

Agora mesmo, estou na dúvida se colocar a tag [api](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) numa Meta pergunta: [É possível receber notificações de perguntas específicas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1386/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-receber-notifica%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-perguntas-espec%c3%adficas), mas a dúvida também vale para o site principal.

Acabo de pesquisar no Metão e achei uma pergunta similar: [*Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que?lq=1)

Comment: Boa pergunta! Eu já quis fazer isso várias vezes, mas sempre acabei desistindo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Algo me diz que *não*

As tags fazem parte da pergunta, e não devem sofrer influência das respostas. Acrescentar uma tag por causa da resposta pode distorcer a pergunta, e até impedir que ela seja respondida.

### Mas algo me diz que *sim*

Uma tag bem colocada em uma pergunta pode ser a diferença entre as pessoas encontrarem ou não o que estão procurando. Tem casos em que a pergunta tem uma resposta unânime, que por acaso corresponde a uma tag que não está na pergunta.

### Então **depende**

Pense duas vezes antes de fazer isso. Depois pense mais duas. Então considere:

- A tag representa a *resposta aceita* da pergunta? A tag representa a *única* resposta possível para a pergunta? Ou pelo menos uma resposta que seja *unânime*? (perigo! subjetivo!)
- A pergunta "assentou"? Se ela está num pico de atividade, evite colocar uma tag pela resposta.
- A tag pode impedir que surjam outras respostas com uma abordagem diferente, mas incompatível com essa tag? Então não coloque!

### Conclusão

Há boas chances de errar fazendo isso, mas um acerto garante +1 dos taxonomistas de plantão.

Comment: Acabo de atualizar a pergunta com um link pro metão. O que acha da discussão lá?

Comment: Ora, pois sim, tem o perigo de converter a pergunta em [camaleão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115/ser%c3%a1-que-esta-%c3%a9-uma-pergunta-camale%c3%a3o) ao adicionar um tag "alienigena" à pergunta inicial. Pensar, importante é.

Comment: Lá fala de levar em conta se a resposta foi aceita, o que geralmente é uma boa ideia. Acrescentei isso na minha resposta.

Comment: Então no meu caso específico tá difícil... Pela minha resposta, API, pela do mgibson, RSS, e pela do Bruno, Email... Não vai caber...

Comment: É, ali acho melhor não. As respostas são todas workarounds, a pergunta quer *notificações* (tem até a tag novo-recurso).

Comment: `Depois pense mais duas`, e depois peça a alguém pra pensar *mais duas*... bom algoritmo :)