# Como ser um usuário mais dedicado no Stack Overflow?

Tags: debate

Gostaria de saber dos usuários com pontuação maior (atualmente de 10k pra cima +/-), como é a rotina deles para conseguirem dar tanta atenção ao site.

Tenho muita curiosidade sobre a rotina deles, se trabalham, como fizeram para aprender tanta coisa e ainda ter tanto tempo disponível para dar respostas tão boas e elaboradas. Se possível também saber a quanto tempo estão nessa busca constante por conhecimento.

Queria muito dicas para chegar nesses níveis de conhecimento, e por fim conseguir dar mais atenção ao site e ajudar a todos.

Comment: Bots cara, são bots. ;)

Comment: Mais uma vez vocês se superaram nas respostas! Não sei nem como marcar uma! Mas acredito que todas vão inspirar a mim e a outras pessoas a melhorar. No meu caso vou precisar abrir mão de certas coisas em prol da minha evolução como profissional, mas acho que vale a pena. Acho a idéia do StackOverflow sensacional e é muito bom saber que tem tantas pessoas que compartilham conhecimento. Não é de graça pois também aprendemos muito ensinando, mas a vontade de ajudar é notável aqui também. Obrigado a todos!

Comment: às vezes eu até tento ajudar, mas acabo ajudando nesses comentários da pergunta, pois muitas vezes pessoas me negativam nas respostas. Quando tenho certeza da resolução, aí eu posto como resposta. Até sugiro edições nas perguntas alheias para torná-las melhores e mais facilmente identificáveis.

Comment: Leia com atenção todas as respostas e considere adicionar a sua [lista de perguntas favoritas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1392/137387) .

Answer (score 58):

## Obter conhecimento

Saber bastante coisa é uma questão que une:

- **Curiosidade**, que todo programador (eu diria qualquer ser humano, mas alguns se viram bem sem ter) deveria ter. Tem que observar os outros em todo lugar. Pesquisar. Querer saber mais, sempre.
- **Experiência**. Ninguém acumula conhecimento de uma hora para outra ou só lendo livros. É um trabalho contínuo. E quem é experiente observa tudo, ouve todo mundo e desenvolve um senso crítico para filtrar o que é bom ou não. Não tem livro que ensina isto. E digo que alguns nunca serão bons nisto. Se fosse alcançável para todo mundo, todos teriam muito sucesso em suas vidas. Querer é importante, mas também precisa poder. É cruel, é injusto, mas é a vida. Se eu tivesse certas características que gostaria e não tenho, não estaria aqui :)
- **Capacidade de aprendizado**. Parte eu acredito que seja característica de personalidade, parte se adquire na infância e adolescência com educação adequada e parte dá para aprender mesmo adulto, tem técnicas para isto. Seria muito extenso falar sobre aqui, acho que ficaria *off-topic* e não tenho autoridade para falar. Ter **atenção aos detalhes** é algo que destaco.
- **Dar valor para o conhecimento**. Por incrível que pareça muitas vezes as pessoas "não tem tempo" para aprender porque ela acha que isto gasta tempo, quando na verdade é o contrário.
- **Gostar do que faz**. Se for um fardo, ninguém vai se dedicar. E ser bom profissional exige dedicação. Vai fazer outra coisa se não gosta do que está fazendo. Arrume outro emprego. Mude sua vida. Infelicidade gera infelicidade. O oposto também.
- **Ouvir os experientes**. Mas questione o que eles dizem. Aprenda com os outros mas exerça um pensamento livre. Não seja um mero seguidor. Isto vale pra vida toda. Alguns experientes se foram há séculos. Começar do zero, querer saber tudo por conta própria não funciona. É incrível, mas algumas pessoas ignoram todo conhecimento acumulado na história.
- **Deixar de lado a teimosia**. Saiba a hora de repensar a estratégia, de ceder, de contornar o problema, buscar alternativas, ajuda. Perguntar também faz parte da evolução.
- **Planejamento e organização**. Estude técnicas para fazer o aprendizado render, para não lhe tomar tempo demais, obter os melhores resultados.
- Deve ter outras coisas que não sei ou não lembro.

Especificamente sobre o SOpt ou mesmo o SO (saber inglês ajuda muito na nossa profissão). **Leia "tudo" o que tem no site**. Não só o que está te interessando agora. Eu vivo lendo coisas no SO. Minha vida profissional mudou desde 2008. Muito do que sou hoje devo ao SO. Muita coisa me ajudou na vida, mas tudo mudou quando o SO foi criado. Leio o SOpt também só pra aprender, mas menos. Claro que não leio tudo, mas aquilo que eu vejo que vai me servir direta ou indiretamente. Mas tenho o leque bem aberto. Com o tempo você desenvolve um filtro melhor.

## Educação

Parte da capacidade de elaboração de conteúdo vem da educação como um todo. Infelizmente no Brasil a maioria das pessoas recebem bem pouca educação e de péssima qualidade. Inclusive em escolas particulares. Eu tive sorte de ter estudado em uma das melhores escolas do Brasil, apesar de ela ser falha em muitos aspectos. E as escolas estão piorando. Elas estão se adaptando à nova geração de pais e filhos e o *marketing* está prevalecendo. Estão cada vez vendendo mais satisfação que educação de verdade. Na verdade eu vejo esta queda da qualidade da educação como um fenômeno mundial.

Não sei como resolver esta situação. Havia uma época que eu podia dizer "salve seu filho e ofereça uma boa educação pra ele". Hoje é difícil conseguir isto a não ser que você seja **muito** rico. Mesmo assim está fácil errar. E obviamente que estou fazendo uma simplificação, não basta só isto. Estar no ambiente certo é fundamental para uma melhor educação. É triste mas é a pura realidade.

O que posso dizer para aplicar agora é: **aprenda aprender**. Como eu gostaria de fazer isto melhor...

## Características pessoais

Nem todo mundo tem as mesmas vantagens e desvantagens. Eu tenho alguns problemas neurológicos que dificultam minha vida. Meus textos mostram um pouco disto. Mesmo conhecendo nossa língua, eu cometo erros (muitos de digitação, outros de construção de frases ou mesmo formatação e organização das informações) que sei que estão errados. Eu não posso evitar. E nem sempre tenho tempo para revisar e consertar. Mesmo quando tenho, nem sempre os enxergo. Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isto mas o que quero dizer é que mesmo tendo limitações você pode compensar com esforço.

**Botar a mão na massa é que produz resultados**. Ninguém consegue nada só observando.

Ser perfeccionista ajuda e atrapalha :) Se eu fosse menos chato e polêmico eu teria mais votos :) Se eu fosse "político populista", como alguns no site, eu teria mais votos. Mas eu prefiro meu estilo, óbvio :). Pago o preço com prazer.

Ache seu estilo. **Foque nas suas qualidades**, não nos seus defeitos.

## Outros efeitos psicológicos

Se você tiver medo de errar, de fazer feio na frente de todo mundo, vai evitar participar. Precisa resolver isto se tiver esse bloqueio. É claro que quando se sabe pouco, sabe que vai errar mais facilmente, e claro que dá mais medo.

Também alguns não têm esse medo e deveriam. Vira e mexe aparece um com pouca capacidade de participação e vai assim mesmo. Alguns acabam atrapalhando de fato. Precisa ter noção quando está atrapalhando e quando está contribuindo pouco. Isso faz um diferença enorme. Você não pode atrapalhar. Mas pode contribuir pouco. Contribuir nada não ajuda treinar. Só a prática ajuda melhorar.

Quero deixar claro que o AP faz(ia) muito pelo site, Talvez mais que ele imagina. Isto pode até não refletir na reputação, mas nem tudo é reputação.

**Seja resiliente**. Muitas vezes será frustrante. O começo é difícil. Estabeleça metas atingíveis e persiga-as. Eu tenho(tinha) as minhas pessoais e vou adaptando frequentemente. Reputação não é meta pra mim, então tenho outros objetivos. (a reputação foi em certo momento, nem percebi, mas hoje não é a reputação que quero e há pessoas com visão muito limitada que não enxergam qual minha motivação, não serei eu que falarei).

Em alguns casos buscar ajuda profissional pode ajudar. Acho que ninguém fará isto só por causa deste site. Mas pode ser que descubra que é algo que pode ajudar a vida como um todo. Há pessoas que têm potencial e só estão precisando de um empurrão para liberar todo ele. Pode ser um problema psicológico, psiquiátrico, neurológico, ou mais específico em pedagogia, e outros fatores que não vêm ao caso aqui.

## Esforço

Este é outro ponto fundamental. Nada cai do céu. Muitas pessoas acham que sim, mesmo que elas discursem que sabem que não. Até certo ponto o esforço vence as limitações. Eu tenho "inveja" das pessoas que conseguem o que querem com pouco esforço. Mas sei que todos precisam se esforçar. Alguns bem mais.

A busca constante por aperfeiçoamento é fundamental para evoluir. E se não estiver muito disposto a isto pode ser frustrante porque o resultado vem lentamente e nem sempre é perceptível.

Parte da minha capacidade de participar é fruto de uma vontade e de um esforço pessoal.

Este é meu grande segredo. Eu sou pior que muita gente aqui em termos profissionais, em conhecimentos específicos. Eu sou o principal usuário de várias das principais *tags* onde tem gente que eu considero absurdamente melhor que eu naquele assunto. Estou nesta posição porque eu me dedico mais que eles. Nada errado com a atitude deles. Cada um na sua. Mas isto é que me fez dar esse retorno. Minha dedicação ao site é que me colocou nesta posição, não meu conhecimento. Embora ele tenha ajudado.

Isto não é modéstia não. Não tenho essa qualidade/defeito :P

## Fundamentos

Faço isto há 35 anos. Tive a vantagem de aprender os fundamentos. Aprendi em uma época que isto é mais valorizado. Sem eles fica difícil aprender todo o resto.

Aí eu vou contar um segredo. Eu respondo sobre muita coisa que eu não sei, que eu não uso. Porque tenho os fundamentos, que as pessoas não dão valor, eu consigo pesquisar, aprender na hora e produzir respostas. Isto não é fácil, simples, não é todo mundo que consegue fazer assim e não acontece do dia pra noite, mas é possível. E este é um dos motivos que estou aqui. Me dá inspiração para aprender mais. Minha participação tem diminuído porque já não é possível o mesmo como era antes.

Hoje com tanta coisa pra aprender as pessoas não estão aprendendo os fundamentos da computação. Elas se concentram nas tecnologias, e isto é um erro. Mesmo quem fez curso superior na área, não aprendeu. As pessoas estão aprendendo as abstrações sem aprender o concreto. Pior, estão aprendendo receitas de bolo sem aprender a **criar**.

Também tive a sorte de trabalhar com algumas pessoas muito boas na hora certa. Eu fiquei 10 anos procurando empregos que me ensinavam algo, sem preocupação com o salário. Depois essa preocupação passou ser secundária, mas ainda é importante para decidir onde trabalhar.

Não ignore o poder do fundamento. O que é bem diferente de ser "acadêmico". Quer arrumar briga? Chame uma pessoa que se preocupa demais com teoria inútil de "acadêmico" :) Eles sabem como é ruim sê-lo. Mas note que não tem nada a ver com o fato de algumas pessoas focarem sua trajetória no campo mais conceitual, mais formal, mais científico, mais... acadêmico. Falo das pessoas que querem aplicar a teoria pura de forma dogmática onde não cabe. O fundamento deve ser aplicado de forma pragmática. E claro que tem hora que o formal puro cabe também. Tem momentos!

## Tempo e motivação

Eu tenho "tempo livre" porque sou dono da minha empresa. Tenho que me dedicar muito a ela, mas não tem ninguém olhando sobre meus ombros o que estou fazendo. Mas tem momentos que eu não posso gastar tempo aqui.

Eu aprendo muita coisa aqui. Por isto participo. Eu estou praticando várias coisas. Eu não vou dar de bonzinho aqui não. Eu estou aqui porque isto me ajuda de alguma forma. Por sorte minha presença ajuda outras pessoas também. O pouco que conheço de psicologia me mostra que as pessoas são egoístas. Até a Madre Tereza. Mas ninguém gosta de admitir isto, e em geral as pessoas têm a "esquizofrenia" de não gostar de pessoas egoístas, mesmo elas mesmas sendo. Então o cérebro fica tentando fazer de conta que isto não acontece. Parte do motivo de eu ter disposição para ajudar aqui é que eu vejo que isto me traz alguma coisa útil. Para algumas pessoas pode funcionar um pouco diferente, mas este é um mecanismo humano universal. E é fortemente presente em todos animais. Mesmo quando as pessoas estão sendo altruístas, no fundo elas estão buscando um ganho paralelo. Pode ser um reconhecimento por parte dos demais, pode ser algo mais intangível, algo que só ela percebe. Não existe altruísmo verdadeiro, só o falso. Alguns vão odiar ler isto e obviamente vão discordar, fazer o que?...

Deixo o SOpt sempre aberto. Para o bem ou para o mal isto me ajuda participar e atrapalhar meu trabalho :) Mas a vontade de estar aqui, de contribuir, de egoisticamente fazer a internet e o mundo ser melhor (já leu isto em algum lugar? :) ), me faz sempre arrumar um tempo.

## Reputação

Tem uma série de técnicas para obtê-la. Algumas simples e comuns, outras menos ortodoxas, algumas polêmicas. Não vou entrar em detalhes para não haver abusos de certas coisas mas algumas coisas fazem você ter mais reputação:

- Responder muito. Óbvio. Perguntar também, mas a diferença de retorno é gritante.
- Responder coisas genéricas. Coisas muito específicas tem público menor.
- Responder coisas que ensinam a todos. Dá mais retorno que algo que só ajuda ao AP. Dê a vara e não o peixe.
- Responder coisas fáceis :) Assim todos podem confirmar que você está certo. Respostas complexas tem poucos votos, mesmo que elas sejam boas.

Algumas dicas:

- Não gosto disto mas: responda o medíocre, ou seja, o que todo mundo concorda.
- De um ar bonitinho ao que escreveu. Isto atrai votos. Não deveria ser assim.
- Invista nas coisas curiosas. Isto atrai mais que deveria.
- Seja completo. Coloque tudo o que puder. Se dedique, não dê uma resposta mais ou menos. O mesmo vale para a pergunta. Mostre muito esforço, mostre que não está ali por preguiça, por participar da brincadeira apenas.
- Tem dias e horários melhores. Divulgue o que escreveu. Faça aparecer. Faça seu conteúdo aparecer.
- Não abandone o que postou, melhore ele. Continue ativo.
- Tente ser o primeiro a responder. Mas se não der, tente ser o melhor.
- Responda o que ficou pra traz. Nem sempre é recompensador em reputação direta, mas ajuda praticar. Se puder escrever qualquer coisa um pouco diferente do que já foi respondido, já vale a postagem.
- Leia muito o que os outros estão fazendo. Identifique o que dá certo. Copie a forma de atuação. Adapte o que não estiver funcionando. Eu copio muito porcamente o [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert).
- Siga as regras, use o site direito. Use as ferramentas do site. Seja ativo em geral. Isto ajuda indiretamente (também arruma alguns inimigos :) ). Isto não é uma indireta, é uma observação geral.
- Já foi mais fácil obter reputação. As pessoas estão votando menos. Alguns usuários vão sempre concorrer com você, alguns ganham votos porque já tem muitos votos. Isto não tem muita solução. Só uma máquina do tempo resolve. Traga usuários novos para o site que estejam dispostos a votar de forma criteriosa.

## Conclusão

Peça ajuda específica sempre que precisar. Acho que podemos usar o meta para ajudar as pessoas melhorarem sua participação, melhorar sua capacidade profissional como um todo.

**Comece fazer!**

Espero que isto ajude na sua vida profissional, na remuneração e talvez em outros aspectos. O que eu sei é que se tiver uma atitude mais ativa, da forma correta, o que não é fácil, acaba sendo recompensado de uma forma ou de outra.

Comment: É verdade utilizadores com muita reputação geram mais votos...

Comment: @JorgeB. obviamente não é a única coisa. Também não quero tirar o mérito que essas pessoas, modéstia bem à parte, sabem como produzir postagens que atraem votos. Eu entreguei os segredos.

Comment: Atenção eu não quis dizer isso, só quis dizer mesmo que a reputação também gera reputação.

Answer (score 32):

O meu percurso pessoal começou no SOen. Não sabia nada de nada. Comecei com perguntas mal formatadas, básicas (do mais básico!) e à procura de um ramo onde me agarrar.

Fui tendo ajuda por lá, por vezes com chuva de `-1` e fui melhorando. No meu caso juntei-me à comunidade do MooTools que me ensinou rios de coisas.

Passado algum tempo comecei a tentar responder no SOen também, a par com as minhas apps que ia desenvolvendo e "debugando".

Eu tenho linguagens preferidas, por paixão e por limite de conhecimento de outras linguagens. Dou atênção especial a essas linguagens e tenho sempre uma aba do browser aberto nas perguntas dessa linguagem. Agora que sou moderador, tenho aberto a página inicial de perguntas, para tentar ajudar se fôr caso de isso.

A estratégia que recomendo é encontrar uma pergunta (respondida ou não) e tentar responder sem ver outras respostas. No final, com o problema resolvido, podes comparar com as respostas que possa haver. Aí vais aprender muito sobre como fazer cada vez melhor. No SOen fiz assim, e muitas vezes chegava 1 hora atrasado em relação às outras respostas. Mas a pouco e pouco fui ficando mais experiente e rápido.

Hoje em dia percebo que em áreas que me sinto em casa é fácil responder de maneira completa e de memória, mas nem sempre foi assim.

> **Fake it 'till you make it!** - ou com outras palavras: quem não arrisca não petisca :=)

Ah, e antes que me esqueça: melhorar uma resposta com conhecimentos novos é sempre muito bom. Por vezes respondo, passado um mês aprendo algo que acrescento à resposta e recebo muito mais votos positivos nos dias/meses seguintes.

Answer (score 31):

Essa pergunta é muito pertinente e pode ser levada mais longe

> *como ser um desenvolvedor dedicado que não apenas resolve os seus próprios problemas, mas ainda consegue tempo para ajudar os demais?*

Seja no SOpt, SOen ou no seu ambiente de trabalho. Um desenvolvedor maduro deve saber como ajudar os demais.

## Questões filosóficas

Muitos desenvolvedores não gostam de ajudar os outros. Eles acham que "dar suporte" a desenvolvedores é se rebaixar a uma categoria inferior.

Outros simplesmente não querem perder seu tempo, mesmo que esse tempo seja gasto contando piadas e bebendo café nos corredores.

Existem várias categorias, mas ao contrário disso, **os melhores desenvolvedores** que conheço possuem caráter oposto:

- Sentem-se responsáveis pelo sucesso do produto ou da empresa como um todo.
- Sentem que ajudar os outros é ter sucesso juntamente com eles.
- Entendem que doar seu tempo para resolver problemas dos outros faz parte de sua missão pessoal, torna o mundo um lugar melhor para todos.
- Economicamente, ajudar os outros, mesmo que em outras empresas, gera um benefício para todos, não é jogar dinheiro fora ou desperdício de tempo. Especificamente dentro de uma empresa, se um funcionário investir seu tempo de forma que ele ajude outros 10 colegas a serem mais produtivos, talvez ele aumente a produtividade mais do que se ele apenas programasse sozinho.

Enfim, a primeira coisa é ter uma mentalidade de trabalho em conjunto, não ser individualista.

## Descubra no que você é bom

Para ajudar as pessoas você precisa dominar alguma coisa. Não sigfnifica saber tudo, mas ao menos como pesquisar detalhes sobre o assunto.

A forma mais fácil de conseguir isso é estudar algo que goste e, quando algum colega tiver um problema relacionado, você senta junto e tenta ajudar como conseguir. Repita isso várias vezes.

## Tempo

Se você mal consegue ter tempo para suas atividades normais, não conseguirá ajudar os outros. No entanto, isso significa que há algum problema e você deve identificar a causa.

Pode ser que seu trabalho seja "desumano". Sua empresa ou gerente não lhe deixa nem respirar? Você não tem tempo de se dedicar a aprender nada, nem de fazer o melhor no seu trabalho? Comece a enviar seu CV para uma empresa que seja verdadeiramente de TI.

Pode ser que você esteja investindo seu tempo na coisa errada. Talvez você desperdice muito do seu tempo com outros coisas e por isso não sobra tempo. Muitas pessoas enrolam no trabalho, outras gastam todo seu tempo vendo maratonas de seriados ou jogando excessivamente vídeo-games. Procure gastar seu tempo com mais sabedoria, concentrando os esforços naquilo que retornará mais benefícios no futuro.

## Não exagere

Muitos usuários aqui dedicam muito tempo ao site. Eu mesmo já fiz isso no início, embora por diversas razões tenha sido obrigado a diminuir o tempo que passo no site. Manter uma participação grande e constante no site é para poucos.

Minha dica é: *não se compare aos outros e não se force a passar tempo demais no site*.

Ficar tempo de mais pode lhe atrapalhar na vida pessoal ou no trabalho. Pode também cansar mentalmente. Você acaba gastando muito tempo de uma vez, depois fica bastante tempo longe.

É melhor estabelecer uma rotina diária limitando o tempo no site, mas com participação constante ao longo do tempo.

## Tenha um objetivo

Por exemplo, defina que você quer gastar, digamos, uma hora por dia para se aperfeiçoar profissionalmente. Considere que bons empregadores vão estar mais do que satisfeitos em você usar um pouco do tempo no trabalho para fazer isso, mas depende muito do ambiente de trabalho. Converse com sua equipe.

Dessa hora, você pode investir 30 minutos para leitura de um artigo ou livro sobre o que você gosta.

O tempo restante você pode dedicar a revisar perguntas e respostas sobre o assunto que está estudando aqui no SOpt. Crie um filtro e comece a olhar. Não se force a responder, apenas foque em entender as perguntas e respostas. Logo você vai notar que pode acrescentar algo. Este é o momento que vale a pena responder.

Na medida em que você for avançando no estudo e no acompanhamento do site, as respostas fluirão mais naturalmente e cada vez mais certeiras.

Note que caso você queira realmente dar um passo maior em sua carreira, talvez precisa dedicar um pouco mais de tempo. Para tirar uma certificação ou fazer uma pós-graduação, por exemplo, você deve se dedicar mais, só lembre de não exagerar.

Comment: O terceiro item da lista `•` é uma filosofia de vida, não apenas no lado profissional, mas, ainda mais no pessoal. Muito bom!

Answer (score 27):

> Gostaria de saber dos usuários com pontuação maior (atualmente de 10k pra cima +/-), como é a rotina deles para conseguirem dar tanta atenção ao site.

Eu dou mais atenção ao site justamente em horário de trabalho. Depois do expediente ou aos finais de semana eu acesso de forma irregular e muitas vezes pelo celular ou tablet. Quando estou acessando por dispositivos móveis eu costumo dizer que estou em *read-only mode*, ou seja, eu só leio, raramente eu escrevo ou faço alguma coisa do tipo.

Em horário de trabalho eu deixo sempre pelo menos duas abas do Stack Overflow abertas, uma para as salas de chat e outra para a página principal, conforme eu resolvo navegar para responder, analisar flags, dentre outras coisas, eu saio abrindo outras abas e depois tendo a voltar para as duas abas que já estavam abertas anteriormente, e fico intercalando esse ciclo durante meu expediente. Geralmente faço isso quando quero dar uma espairecida do meu trabalho, já que o Stack Overflow para mim é um entretenimento, quase igual se eu estivesse jogando um jogo :)

Às vezes, quando eu quero responder perguntas de uma tag em específico eu deixo uma aba aberta só para ela, e fico atento às notificações de novas perguntas nela. Já fiz muito disso com a [aba Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pageSize=15), mas já faz um tempo que eu não faço e tenho ficado mais na página inicial mesmo. Mas é legal você saber que tem essa possibilidade.

Independente de estar ou não antenado nas novas perguntas assim que são postadas é sempre é bom dar uma vasculhada em perguntas antigas, sempre tem alguma coisa que você deixou passar e que pode ser interessante. Ao vasculhá-las você pode encontrar boas respostas e então votar nelas, ou descobrir que muitas delas ainda não tem respostas ou tem respostas incompletas, e aí você pode postar a sua com calma pois a pergunta não está mais em *destaque* por estar na página inicial (não confunda com a aba "destaque").

> Tenho muita curiosidade sobre a rotina deles, se trabalham.

Como eu disse anteriormente, eu trabalho. Até fevereiro eu trabalhava em uma Eletrometalúrgica, onde a cultura é bem diferente de uma empresa de TI. Naquela empresa ninguém tinha muitas liberdades, qualquer um que fosse *pego* assistindo um vídeo no YouTube ou qualquer coisa do tipo em horário de serviço ia no mínimo ficar mal falado e com olhares desconfiados para cima dele. Mas ainda assim eu participava bastante do SO. Só tinha eu e meu chefe de programadores, portanto qualquer um que olhasse para a minha tela não faria a menor ideia do que eu estava fazendo, se eu estivesse lendo uma pergunta poderiam achar que eu estava pesquisando uma dúvida minha, se eu estivesse escrevendo algo poderiam achar que eu estava documentando algo, enfim, nunca precisei esconder minha tela e sempre tive uma liberdade relativamente alta quando o assunto era participar do SO.

Hoje eu trabalho em uma empresa de tecnologia, e aqui é bem mais flexível em inúmeros pontos. Aqui por exemplo, a própria empresa fornece o *headset* para os funcionários, por ser uma ferramenta quase tão importante quanto o mouse :), enquanto em empresas que não são de tecnologia não se costuma ver o povo escutando música enquanto trabalha.

Enfim, independente de onde eu trabalhei, participar do SO ou SOPT se tornou um hábito que eu tenho e que eu nunca precisei esconder, e eu nunca considerei que estava fazendo algo de errado ao dedicar parte do meu tempo no trabalho para participar daqui, acredito que o que aprendo com isso se reflete diretamente em meu trabalho de forma positiva.

> Como fizeram para aprender tanta coisa e ainda ter tanto tempo disponível para dar respostas tão boas e elaboradas. Se possível também saber a quanto tempo estão nessa busca constante por conhecimento.

Desde que eu me formei eu comecei a estudar por conta própria, sempre tive muita curiosidade e cada vez mais me interessava por programação, estava cada dia estudando uma coisa diferente. Isso no começo era legal para ter uma boa ideia sobre tudo mas depois de um tempo eu percebi que eu não sabia a fundo quase nada. Isso inclusive ficou bem claro para mim quando comecei a participar do SO em inglês, pois eu penei bastante, tive muitas respostas negativadas e duras críticas por várias vezes.

Isso coincidiu de ser um pouco antes de eu começar a estudar para tirar certificação Java. Ao estudar para essa certificação eu pesquisei e vi muitas pessoas falando muito bem do livro [SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Exam 310-065 1st Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071591060), eu baixei ele e comecei a ler. Eu fiquei tão deslumbrado e maravilhado com as primeiras páginas dele que eu fui correndo comprar o livro físico na Amazon, eu queria **ter** ele, poder folheá-lo, e etc.

Com aquele livro eu descobri uma nova maneira de estudar por conta própria, os assuntos sempre tinham começo, meio e fim, quando um assunto era tratado me era mostrado os prós, os contras, as alternativas, as motivações das coisas serem do jeito que elas são, e eu realmente **aprendi** com esse livro. Esse para mim foi o melhor livro de programação que já li até hoje.

> Queria muito dicas para chegar nesses níveis de conhecimento, e por fim conseguir dar mais atenção ao site e ajudar a todos.

Considerando tudo que eu disse no item anterior, minha dica é você se especializar em alguma coisa. Experimente pegar algo que você mais gosta de trabalhar e ir a fundo nela. Pesquise quais são os melhores livros desse assunto e compre um, esmiúce ele, seja curioso, seja inquisitivo, e o mais importante: aprenda!

Depois disso, abra a aba dessa tag aqui no SOPT e fique esperando aparecer a próxima pergunta dela, assim que aparecer você poderá abrí-la e responde-la de forma detalhada e completa, pois você realmente dominará o assunto. Perceberá que os votos virão muito mais facilmente depois disso :)

Comment: *"assuntos sempre tinham começo, meio e fim, quando um assunto era tratado me era mostrado os prós, os contras, as alternativas, as motivações das coisas serem do jeito que elas são"* falta muito isto para as pessoas aprenderem e na maioria das vezes nem por falta de informação disponível.

Comment: @bigown sim, é importante saber isso para dominar verdadeiramente o assunto, mas nem todo mundo se preocupa com isso

Answer (score 23):

## Gostaria de saber dos usuários com pontuação maior (atualmente de 10k pra cima +/-), como é a rotina deles para conseguirem dar tanta atenção ao site.

Uso duas telas. Em uma faço meu trabalho normal (aquele que me sustenta), e no outro mantenho a página inicial do Stack Overflow em Português aberta.

Normalmente leio o título de todas as perguntas, mas me interesso mais por responder às perguntas que fazem parte de conhecimentos que domino diariamente.

Não tento responder a tudo. Respondo o que tenho vontade.

Para votar, meus critérios normalmente são, em resumo:

- Perguntas úteis;
- Respostas boas e objetivas.

Consideráveis vezes não sei como responder à pergunta adequadamente. Faço uma pequena pesquisa antes de responder.

Raramente reviso minhas perguntas e respostas. Reviso com alguma frequência perguntas e respostas dos outros, até porque já aconteceu muitas vezes de a pergunta começar de um jeito e terminar de outro completamente diferente. Infelizmente não é todo mundo que tem um bom poder de síntese.

#### Tenho muita curiosidade sobre a rotina deles, se trabalham, como fizeram para aprender tanta coisa e ainda ter tanto tempo disponível para dar respostas tão boas e elaboradas. Se possível também saber a quanto tempo estão nessa busca constante por conhecimento.

Sim, trabalho. Muito.

O aprendizado vem de como você encara seu trabalho. Você pode usar a solução que conhece pra tudo, ou ter algum espírito crítico e questionar se esta é a melhor forma de resolver aquele problema. Normalmente não é a melhor forma (95% das vezes). Este espírito crítico normalmente aparece em 3 situações:

- Se você leva muito tempo pra resolver o problema;
- Se a solução fica prolixa demais, difícil de dar manutenção, exageradamente complexa;
- Se você já ouviu falar de alguma solução melhor, mas nunca conseguiu aprendê-la.

Filosoficamente, diria que minha busca por conhecimento existe desde que nasci. A busca por conhecimento parte de três coisas: insatisfação, curiosidade e paciência.

Recomendo também leituras aleatórias, hábito que chamam por aí de [afiar a serra](https://www.stephencovey.com/7habits/7habits-habit7.php). Meus sites favoritos são o [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/) e o [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/).

## Queria muito dicas para chegar nesses níveis de conhecimento, e por fim conseguir dar mais atenção ao site e ajudar a todos.

As minhas são:

- Não tente responder a tudo. Especialize-se em alguma linguagem ou *framework* que goste. A curva de aprendizado é mais interessante;
- Leia as respostas dos outros. Aprenda com elas;
- Junte o hábito de responder ao seu trabalho diário. Ou seja, não responda a só aquilo que você conheça perfeitamente. Arrisque um pouco e aplique isso ao seu sistema;
- Guarde um tempo do seu dia para tentar implementar algo que você não conheça bem. Eu guardo normalmente duas horas;
- Uma resposta boa pode ter duas linhas. Escrever respostas imensas não faz ela ficar boa, até porque dificilmente todo mundo vai ler tudo;
- Dois monitores são legais. Se você ainda não tem, providencie.

## Sobre ajudar os outros

Grande parte da minha motivação de ajudar foram alguns episódios que vivi na minha trajetória profissional.

Um deles, bastante marcante, foi no meu primeiro emprego com carteira assinada. Me jogaram um manual de Delphi no colo, outro de SQLWindows, e disseram:

> Vire-se.

Naturalmente, o que fazemos numa situação dessas é começar a leitura do livro pelo começo. Claro que, alguns minutos depois, a leitura fica mais dinâmica. Passamos as páginas mais rápido e vamos diretamente para conhecimentos mais novos.

Mas, e quando tempo se perde desenvolvendo essa dinâmica de estudo?

Há, ainda, outro agravante: a empresa não disponibilizava acesso à internet para a maioria dos usuários em horário de expediente (!). Pedir ajuda para outros programadores mais experientes era pedir pra ouvir zombaria, ser motivo de piada, e assim por diante.

Além disso, lembro de os códigos serem numa qualidade deplorável. E estamos falando de empresas que desenvolvem para empresas privadas, tribunais de justiça, outros órgãos públicos.

Posso dizer que minha principal motivação é a de me solidarizar com o desamparo. Pouca gente sabe o que é ser programador e não saber por onde começar, na maioria dos casos.

Por fim, o site me empurra pra sempre estar estudando, sempre ir atrás de mais coisas. Incentiva, também, a procurar oportunidades de trabalho cada vez melhores.

Não sei se é apenas isso. Depois acho que vou revisar essa resposta e melhorá-la.

Comment: Programador sem internet. Passei por isso no início. Empresas vivem na idade das pedras, tratando funcionários com desconfiança. Bloqueiam a internet com medo do funcionário ficar no Facebook e quem quer aprender se dá mal. Eu lembro de correr para casa no almoço, pesquisar tudo o que podia, salvar num pendrive e levar para a empresa para poder tentar continuar a trabalhar. Triste, mas o importante é não desistir.

Comment: @utluiz Sorte que hoje em dia tem 3G e 4G, mas na época era tudo bem difícil. Eles ainda liberavam alguns sites essenciais (para a empresa), como  o site da Microsoft. Aí um belo dia eu aprendi a dar *bypass* no proxy e estudei o que precisava assim mesmo.

Comment: Eu sou do tempo que era difícil importar livro e quase não tinha nada nacional :)

Comment: @bigown Cheguei a importar alguns livros também, principalmente os que falavam de "hacks". Eram muito úteis pra propor soluções criativas, mas aí vieram os e-books logo após, e perdi o gás de comprar livro importado.

Comment: Excelentes todas as respostas!!!
Principalmente as dicas de sites!