# Porque necessitamos de tanta reputação para comentar?

Tags: debate, comentários

Bom vou ser direto, só quero saber porque eu preciso de tanta reputação para comentar na pergunta de outra pessoa?
Vou explicar o porque dessa pergunta, as vezes eu sei como responder a uma pessoa porém preciso que ela especifique mais a sua pergunta, mas eu não tenho como pedir isso para ele porque não posso comentar, assim me dificulta ganhar reputação ;-;.

Comment: Relacionado: [É possível (e desejável) reduzir o requisito para comentar?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/817/3117)

Comment: Essa é realmente uma boa pergunta. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Vou falar o que eu acho, não tenho certeza se é a resposta certa.

São dois motivos principais:

1. Qualquer um pode fazer publicações no site e é fácil fazer uma conta, se fossem liberados comentários para usuários sem reputação seria muito fácil fazer contas para "atrapalhar" o site (*flood*, *spams* e comentários ofensivos);
2. É uma forma de garantir que o usuário conheça ao menos o básico do site, como ele funciona, etc. Antes de sair comentando por aí.

   Ex.: A maioria das pessoas chega aqui pensando que o site é um fórum, isso é muito comum.

Realmente é complicado essa questão de quando você precisa que o AP especifique melhor a pergunta e não pode fazer comentários, mas conseguir 50 pontos de reputação não é difícil, você só precisa de um pouco de paciência.

Talvez algumas dessas perguntas possam te ajudar:

- [Como ser um usuário mais dedicado no Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4329/18246)
- [Como aumentar a minha Reputação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5050/18246)

Comment: Acho que é mais o 1 mesmo, embora o 2 seja um efeito colateral interessante (ainda que não esteja sendo muito eficaz). Sempre tem uma maneira melhor de garantir a usabilidade para todos, o novato e para os experientes sem causar transtornos, só dá mais trabalho implementar.

Comment: Realmente deve ter uma forma de garantir melhor usabilidade para todos. E, pessoalmente, eu acho que essa questão dos comentários é uma das mais delicadas, porque realmente atrapalha (e muito) os novatos. Seria interessante, talvez, uma fila de análise para comentários de usuários com reputação < 50 combinada a um limite de comentários por dia/hora/qualquer coisa.

Comment: Certamente é uma possibilidade.

Comment: Realmente não faz sentido permitir que usuários sem reputação faça perguntas sem a possibilidade de comentar. Ou impede de fazer perguntas, ou libera os comentários (comentário de novatos poderia ser marcado com fundo amarelo), porque do jeito que está, força o novato a cometer erros como "tentar conversar ou tirar dúvidas na área de resposta", e isso parece ser recorrente.

Comment: @Orion, usuários novatos podem adicionar comentários na suas próprias publicações, mesmo não tendo reputação. Creio eu que a maioria dos usuários novatos vêm ao SOpt justamente para _fazer_ uma pergunta e não para _responder_ uma pergunta, logo, se o usuário fazer uma pergunta, poderá comentar livremente na sua publicação.

Answer (score 3):

Até acho correcto que no SO seja necessário um certo nível de reputação (50 pontos) para podermos comentar para não existir comentário "sem nexo" no entanto, no aqui no SOmeta acho que poderiam baixa o nível de reputação para que não seja necessário, como acontece agora comigo, fazer uma resposta para demonstrar a minha opinião.
Dado ser um utilizador ocasional do SO torna-se um pouco difícil ganhar reputação.

Comment: Acredite, está ridiculamente facil obter 50 pontos no site ultimamente. Quando entrei, realmente era meio complicado, e a galera mais antiga entao... Mas agora, com bem mais usuarios e bem mais perguntas pra responder, com 2 respostas ou 2 perguntas bem feitas, você estoura esse limite facilmente :)

Comment: eu pessoalmente concordo com o Articuno, eu já vi gente com uma dia de participação passar do 150, então 50 em uma semana não é tão complicado, acho que estes minimos 50 pontos são necessários sim para ver se o usuário realmente vai ter um minimo comprometimento.