# Como aumentar reputação?

Tags: debate

Como posso aumentar a reputação do stack para poder ao menos votar em uma resposta útil?
Estou percorrendo várias páginas do site para aumentar minha reputação mas só ganhei medalhas. Como proceder?

Comment: Perguntando ou respondendo.

Comment: Outra duplicata: [Como aumentar a minha Reputação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5050/como-aumentar-a-minha-reputação)

Comment: Indiretamente prestando atenção às regras do site. E talvez lendo https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4329/101