# Por que as pessoas precisam responder o que não sabem ou o que não ajuda corretamente?

Tags: debate, respostas, comunidade, respostas-erradas

Tenho notado um aumento nas respostas dadas em perguntas ruins, duplicadas, ou mesmo boas, mas que a resposta não ajuda tanto assim.

Nem sei se aumentou a quantidade, mas a percepção é que isso tem acontecido mais em relação às respostas boas.

Algumas pessoas parecem que querem responder qualquer coisa, sem ver o que a qualidade da pergunta, se isso ajudará várias pessoas, se já foi respondido antes, e principalmente, se ela tem condições de dar uma boa resposta que ensine algo.

Tenho notado que alguns usuários experientes no site tem respondido cada vez mais qualquer pergunta, e muitas vezes de forma equivocada ou pelo menos incompleta, levando pessoas aprenderem errado.

Uma das razões de ter tanta gente fazendo coisas erradas é que elas estão aprendendo coisas erradas, e isso se dá muito porque as fontes ensinam assim.

Não seja essa pessoa que apenas resolve pontualmente um problema da pessoa e não ensina ela fazer o certo. Você resolve o problema que impedia a compilação ou que apresentava o resultado errado, mas deixa essa pessoa com a falsa sensação que agora ela sabe fazer.

Preciso colocar o que essas respostas são:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

- **Qual a necessidade de fazer isto? É por causa dos pontos? É para se sentir útil?**
- **Acha legal ficar perpetuado na internet que sua resposta está ensinando pessoas fazerem algo errado?**
- **Ou acha legal ficar resolvendo o exercício das pessoas? Que mérito isso tem?**

Pior ainda quando equivale a um exercício mas é trabalho que a pessoa pegou e não tem ideia de como fazer.

Como há cada vez menos atividade de usuários mais qualificados fica cada vez mais difícil classificar bem essas respostas e algumas dessas respostas andam tendo alguns votos positivos de pessoas que não entendem sobre aquilo. Está ganhando votos nas respostas que resolvem o furo no pneu mas deixa o carro no estado acima.

**Fica o alerta para as pessoas que leem as respostas:** boa parte das respostas mais novas no SOpt, mesmo algumas com alguns positivos não possuem qualidade e não ensinam corretamente.

E é uma pena porque é muito comum que as pessoas que estão aprendendo acabam aceitando essas como respostas válidas. Se os experientes não fizerem o certo tudo vai se perdendo. É tão difícil ter o mínimo compromisso com a qualidade? Querem ter no currículo uma quantidade de respostas ruins?

**Isso é uma inversão de valores.** Ajudar a ir para o precipício não é algo bom.

Não estou falando de respostas de novatos que é outro problema.

Não dá para olhar um pouco mais para a comunidade em vez de beneficiar uma necessidade do indivíduo?

Note que esta não é exatamente uma pergunta, mas um alerta e uma porta para o debate, algo normal no meta.

Comment: Os famosos ***score hunters***, respondendo ao que não dominam direito com o argumento de *"o importante é tentar ajudar"*

Comment: As pessoas que estão negativando poderiam dizer o motivo. Acham que o debate não é válido? São contra a ideia de só responder quando se sabe o assunto?

Comment: Gostaria de fazer um comentário até um pouco idiota talvez, mas vamos lá... Se algum de nós percebemos que alguém deu uma resposta ruim, que não vai ajudar a pessoa e até ensina-la a fazer a coisa errada, então não seria só responder com uma resposta melhor e negativar a ruim? E se a pessoa fez uma pergunta ruim, como por exemplo pedindo resposta de trabalho e etc, não é só fechar a pergunta como fora de escopo e em determinado tempo ela será excluída junto com as respostas? Não sei, as ferramentas atuais parecem resolver pra mim.

Comment: Digo isso pois acredito que se alguém viu que uma resposta é ruim, quer dizer que essa pessoa tenha no minimo a competência pra apontar os erros da resposta, e talvez até elaborar uma melhor. Eu acredito que existam os score hunters mas também aqueles que só querem ajudar... Outra coisa é que o mundo da tecnologia evolui constantemente, uma resposta que era boa em 2017 pode ser uma resposta ruim hoje, então acredito que se a gente tenha esse conhecimento, basta apontar onde está o erro ou dar uma resposta melhor

Comment: @Raizant A princípio "é só fechar" mesmo, o problema é que são poucos os que têm atuado fechando perguntas (muitos já têm pontuação suficiente mas quase nunca fecham nada). Então a pergunta fica lá, aberta por mais tempo que deveria e recebendo respostas ruins (e nesse caso não caberia dar outra resposta, já que a pergunta é off - nos casos em que a pergunta não é off, eu costumo dar outra resposta se achar pertinente, mas nem sempre a regra de "escreva outra resposta" é aplicável). Pior é quando as respostas ruins recebem positivos ou são aceitas, aí o sistema não apaga mais...

Comment: ... Então o problema é que faltam mais pessoas para ajudarem no site, seja votando para fechar ou orientando os demais (as ferramentas estão lá, falta mais gente usando-as). Outro ponto é que muitas vezes a gente comenta o que está errado mas a pessoa se recusa a corrigir, alguns xingam e outros começam a dar negativos de vingança. Para evitar esse stress, muitos ficam com receio de comentar (não é o ideal, mas infelizmente é assim).

Comment: Entendi, não sabia dessa regra da resposta aceita e com votos positivos não poder deletar... apesar que quase sempre perguntas de "como faço esse exercício" são negativadas... 

Qual a pontuação pra poder votar pra fechar? Geralmente eu sinalizo, uma vez que não achei essa opção de votar pra fechar. :/

Comment: @Raizant As regras que o sistema usa para apagar automaticamente [estão aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) - veja que mesmo se a resposta for negativada, se for aceita o sistema não apaga. E para votar pra fechar, [precisa de 3000 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) - esse é o problema, são poucos usuários com essa pontuação, e desses somente uma pequena parte usa os votos de fechamento. Mas sinalizando vc já ajuda, pois ela vai pra [fila de análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close) (mesmo assim, são poucos os que atuam nesta fila)

Comment: As vezes eu tento responder, quando minha resposta não recebe algum negativo eu fico feliz, já considero que foi uma boa resposta.

Comment: @Raizant Sobre o seu primeiro comentário. É exatamente o que tentamos incentivar todos dias, mas são POUQUÍSSIMOS fazendo a maior parte do trabalho sobre isso e uma maioria esmagadora fazendo ao "contrário", eles *respondem a perguntas ruins e torcem para não receber downs*, acreditando que o que importa é ajudar, sendo que na verdade prejudica o autor da pergunta e futuros visitantes.

Comment: Inclusive essa postagem do Antonio é justamente uma **tentativa** de alertar as pessoas, porque orientar um a um parece que não esta tendo efeito. Tem gente que até concorda, mas eu duvido que tenham entendido as orientações ou motivações.

Comment: Vou deixar um conselho controverso (como não sou mod e não tenho intenção de me candidatar tão cedo posso sugerir esse tipo de coisa :D). Pelo que entendi dos comentários do Guilherme parece que os CMs já estão alertando usuários individualmente. Eu ainda assim colocaria uma lista de "respostas ruins de usuários experientes" na pergunta, mais ou menos como fiz na pergunta sobre os problemas do URI. Não é *name e shame* e sim um recurso para ilustrar o problema e definir o corte. Eu mesmo costumo ser bem leniente com usuários novos e posso estar sendo parte do problema sem saber.

Comment: Além de educar para não dar respostas ruims para perguntas péssimas, uma lista também define melhor o critério de corte e potencialmente tira o grilo da cabeça de usuários experientes que gostam de interagir com usuários novos. Acho importante exemplificar o problema para não desistimular respostas em perguntas de iniciantes (já que boa parte das perguntas de iniciantes tem algum problema).

Comment: @Raizant o maior problema são os que só querem ajudar. Eles querem, mas não conseguem e criam problemas. E tem acontecido muito, e com usuários com pontuação, não são os novatos, até porque os novatos desistem quando veem que não estão à altura. OS que tem pontuação não desistem mesmo postando um monte de coisa errada. Você indica que ela está errando e ela não corrige, ela não muda a atitude, ou seja, ela quer ajudar, mas sem se preocupar com a qualidade. Quem quer a qualidade não insiste nisso e não chega ser um problema. Falo de quem faz respostas ruins hoje. O resto já foi respondido aqui.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly o problema é a teimosia, estou falando das pessoas que já foram alertadas mas continuam fazendo isso. OP cara toma um monte de negativo, recebe comentário dizendo dos problemas, não corrige, não apaga, continua postando respostas ruins que mais desensinam que ensinam. Essas pessoas sabem quem são, não vou expô-las diretamente, mas elas sabem. Tem quem eventualmente apaga quando é bem grave. Tem quem não apaga quando não recebe negativos, então só porque as pessoas cansaram de dar negativos na mesmo e sabe que não adianta, elas acham que estão bem.

Comment: @Maniero, entendi. Me parece um comportamento problemático mesmo. Perdão pela tangente mas como os CMs entram em contato com usuários nesse tipo de caso? Eles enviam um email? Depois que um CM entra em contato com um usuário desses há algum canal para o usuário responder e conversar com o CM?

Comment: Em geral por comentário mesmo. A comunidade também o faz.

Comment: A preocupação em obter respostas ruins deve incomodar mais ao site do que a própria pessoa que publicou a pergunta. Será por quê? Será pra manter o site como referência em respostas boas? Por que uma pessoa só deve responder se for um expert no assunto? Por que ao dar um downvote não é solicitado o motivo?

Comment: @CarlosAndrade exatamente isso, sites com respostas ruins tem de monte por aí, quem quer o ruim vai em todos esses lugares, quem quer o bom vem aqui. E só dá certo se o ruim for expurgado.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade O propósito do site é ser um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, então a qualidade das respostas é mais importante que dar ajuda individual (quem pergunta e responde deve se adequar ao site, não o contrário) - [leia aqui](/q/8045/112052) e [aqui](/q/7256/112052) para entender melhor. Sobre poder votar sem dar o motivo, já foi discutido várias vezes ([aqui](/q/652/112052) e principalmente [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436) <- este só tem em inglês, mas lá explica todos os motivos e porque isso provavelmente não mudará tão cedo...)

Comment: Olá @CarlosAndrade não precisa apenas uma pessoa a responder, mas é bom que todos que venham a responder façam testes, tenham certeza do que estão falando, só que muito do que tem ocorrido é a pergunta dizer X e a pessoa dá a resposta Y, e essas respostas acabam geralmente sendo cópias de outros sites e geralmente não são testadas, isso tem ocorrido muito, por parte de um grande numero de usuários. Sobre dar downvote e justificar ou não já tem postagem especifica https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=comentar+downvote. Aqui o assunto é especifico sobre o problema de responder

Comment: Outros -3 hoje, será então que algumas pessoas concordam que as respostas no site devem ser chutes? E que qualidade não é prioridade? Ou então que o foco do site deveria ser atuar como helpdesk ou como um fórum, ao estilo anos "2000"? .... Bom, se não for nada disso poderiam explicar o porque discordam?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é curioso que vem vários juntos depois de tanto tempo, ou seja, é grupo votando junto. Além de não gostarem de qualidade.

Comment: Já são 6 downvotes. Confesso que estou surpreso com a quantidade de votos contra sobre um assunto que, pelo menos em teoria, iria beneficiar a todos. Um site de qualidade ajuda tantos os novatos quanto os experientes (opnião pessoal) e para manter a qualidade, não podemos deixar o SO virar "_Casa-da-mãe-joana_". Eu aprendi e ainda estou aprendendo muito com as regras do site e comportamento dos mais users mais experientes e moderados.

Comment: Tenho certeza que aqueles quem estão negativando são os usuários que ensinam ou gostam de aprender que em python que para fazer um split duma lista em sub listas precisa sim usar numpy, em javascript para saber se uma propriedade está presente nesse objeto deve se converter o objeto em array e iterar, que em C# para converter a entrada do usuário basta um convert, que em SQL embarcado o correto é passar a entrada do cliente direto numa consulta, usa laços for e while em lisp e haskell, numa divisão por variável denominador zero nunca vai acontecer, que moeda se trabalha com float sim,.........

Comment: Bom sobre os negativos na pergunta, quem tem compromisso com o site (não só com a qualidade) se expõe aqui, comenta (mesmo que seja para discordar), tem interesse em que as coisas melhorem, quem não o faz, só tem interesses próprios, como marketing pessoal, helpdesk e ganhar ups. Isso é ***inversão de valores*** (e devo dizer que tem até veteranos descompromissados). São poucos com compromisso de verdade com o site.

Comment: Eu quero é ver ao menos um desses votantes negativos ter a coragem de assumir que são favoráveis a respostas erradas no site. Não é possível um usuário votar contra a comunidade se esforçar para melhorar a qualidade das respostas. **Vocês, votantes negativos, querem mais respostas ineficientes, não funcionais e de baixa qualidade?** ou não entenderam o que está escrito e só leram o nome do moderador que vocês não gostam?

Comment: Há um padrão, as pessoas que negativam este post são as mesmas que que positivam coisas ruins e negativam coisas certas, ou porque não sabem que está certo, ou porque não gostam de ver algo melhor postado. Eu fiz uma avaliação, e alguns que negativaram aqui são os que negativam praticamente só uma pessoa no site, portanto de forma tendenciosa. Não há compromisso com o site.

Comment: @Maniero, se há um padrão claramente orquestrado de votos desses usuários, já não se configura abuso e manipulação do sistema de votação da parte dos mesmos? Acrescento a isso o fato dessa votação negativa estar prejudicando o desenvolvimento da comunidade, pois ao invés de nos desgastarmos tentando entender os motivos desses votos poderíamos estar discutindo estratégias, alternativas e recomendações para o aprimoramento de nossas respostas.

Comment: Não é fácil você provar fraude, e só fraude pode ser punida, mas tem usuário que está por um fio de dar a prova. Pra mim o pior é a pessoa não querer mostrar sua cara aqui. Elas são corajosas pra fazer anonimamente.

Comment: Gostaria de ver a opinião de mais pessoas, talvez o pessoal do PT e Moçambique, outras comunidades falantes de portugues o pessoal do brasil acaba monopolizando aqui.

Comment: @Danizavtz não tem monopolização, ao contrário tem muito BR avacalhando o site, esse papo de monopólio não tem sentido, os unicos que tem posse do site são a empresa, o que você deve estar falando é de algum tipo de "centralização". Bom, se até os BRs avacalham por aqui, significa que não tem haver com ser BR, ser PT, ou ser de qualquer outro lugar, o problema é um minimo de gente lutando pela qualidade para que não nos tornemos um helpdesk inútil, cheio de respostas gambiarras, contra uma maioria (independente de nacionalidade) querendo agregar pontos para si mesmos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques e tem o pior, fraude de positivos em postagem de baixa qualidade no site principal. O que ocorre é que a empresa pensa diferente da moderação no quesito "botar ordem" e "agradar pessoas". A moderação (e os usuários engajados) tem muito mais preocupação com qualidade do que a empresa (falo isso sem medo de errar), só que quem tem as melhores ferramentas pra lidar com isso é só a empresa. Se dependesse da moderação,o site nunca teria juntado tanto problema. Inclusive, quase todos que implicam com o sistema e moderação são justo os "ficha-suja", mas não podemos expor fraudes aqui.

Comment: O ponto importante (núcleo da pergunta, mas que tiraram do foco completamente) é justamente: não é todo mundo que tem condição de dar respostas boas para a maioria das perguntas, por isso deviam responder só o que dominam de fato **e** atende ao objetivo do site. Só que algumas pessoas que não entendem o site (ou não estão nem aí, cada vez parece mais), por uma questão de ego, querem participar "à força" sem o devido preparo e condição para o nível esperado. Aí começa a conversinha fiada, downvote por vingança, upvote em porcaria. A pessoa além de não ter condição de fazer bem feito, avacalha.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/505798/minhas-vari%c3%a1veis-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a3o-sendo-contadas-no-c%c3%b3digo essa pergunta seria um caso?

Comment: @Raizant aqui estamos falando de respostas. Você viu algum problema aí?

Comment: @Maniero `Qual a necessidade de fazer isto? É por causa dos pontos? É para se sentir útil?` `Acha legal ficar (...)?` `Ou acha legal (...)? Que mérito isso tem?`
-1 Acredito que seja válido discutir o assunto, mas acho o formato inadequado. Entendo que o assunto dessa pergunta possa ser frustrante para o autor, mas noto um teor passivo-agressivo no texto, especialmente nas seções que destaquei, e isto acaba trazendo um tom de desabafo/sermão ao invés de um tom de discussão

Comment: @danielbb ok, anotado, o seu comentário faz o mesmo.

Comment: @Maniero No meu comentário, acredito ter feito uma crítica direta e impessoal sobre um ponto específico do seu texto, não compreendo como seja equivalente às seções que levantei do seu texto. 
E ainda supondo que meu comentário fizesse o mesmo, não acho que um erro justificaria o outro

Comment: @danielbb mas continua não ajudando o debate que você parece defender. E que nem era a intenção, era um alerta para as pessoas pensarem antes de fazer as postagens, ou seja, é um sermão. Eu me concentrei na parte que você queria um debate, mas eu estava enganado você se concentrou em criticar o texto apenas, ser direto não torna o comentário melhor.

Comment: @Maniero `mas continua não ajudando o debate que você parece defender` O meu comentário (assim como o voto negativo) é uma tentativa de elevar o debate. Entendo que as pessoas seriam mais receptivas aos pedidos de mudança de comportamento, se tais pedidos tivessem o tom de alerta/ensinamento, ao invés de sermão/desabafo, pois são poucas as pessoas que, no seu tempo livre, decidem ler e acatar um sermão na internet (estando elas na razão ou não).

Comment: @danielbb infelizmente não elevou, foi só a crítica ao meu texto sem nada debater sobre o assunto em questão. As pessoas podem não ser/acatar sermão, e continuarão recebendo negativos por respostas ruins. Se você tivesse chego no dia pra falar alguma coisa, ajudaria, dois meses depois já é tarde, não ajuda., a não ser que fosse algo que ajudasse as pessoas responderem melhor, não foi o caso. E outro detalhe importante, voltamos para o começo, você critica o sermão, mas fez um, foi a única coisa que fez.

Comment: @Maniero Minha intenção era elevar o debate do site como um todo, e não especificamente deste tópico, ao  separar  com o meu voto o conteúdo bom do conteúdo que pode ser melhorado. Apenas comentei pq muitos apreciam feedback e pq você solicitara em comentário anterior que `As pessoas que estão negativando poderiam dizer o motivo`.

Comment: @danielbb foi anotado e entendido, conforme o exposto acima.

Answer (score -1):

Cara o meu problema com a comunidade é o modo que funciona, gostaria de uma comunidade plural. que represente o tipo de programador que existe nas comunidades que falam português.

Do modo que funciona hoje é ah se o cara tem +10k rep (então eu dou +1, e esse cara recebe no mínimo 4)

Porque não falar do corporativismo com quem já é usuário antigo e possui alta reputação? Porque eles recebem mais pontos positivos que os novatos (em relação a uma pergunta com qualidade similar [usuário alta rep vs baixa rep]).

Eu não vejo a comunidade se reciclando e acolhendo os novos, nem investindo em pessoas que possuem potencial.

> assumir que são favoráveis a respostas erradas no site

Essa não é a questão, você está tentando levar a discussão para a dialética do certo ou errado. Gostaria de respostas plurais. De mais pessoas. Que pudessem representar todos os níveis de programadores (jr, pl, sr, especialista) e que eu pudesse escolher que tipo de resposta melhor se adequa ao meu caso de uso.

As vezes eu só quero uma resposta que funcione, as vezes quero algo eficiente, as vezes quero uma versão funcional, uma mesma versão que seja orientado à objeto, isso é pra exemplificar.

> Vocês, votantes negativos, querem mais respostas ineficientes, não funcionais e de baixa qualidade?

Eu quero uma resposta que funcione, não quero estar certo. Existem várias respostas certas, não apenas uma resposta do cara mais legal da comunidade ou do vascaíno ou do deus do carnaval.
Faz parte do meu trabalho analisar qual é a melhor resposta para o meu caso de uso.

Enfim, esses são meus 2 centavos para a discussão.

Comment: "*Eu quero uma resposta que funcione, não quero estar certo*" -  aí que tá, a ideia do site é ser um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, contendo - idealmente - as respostas mais corretas possíveis (pode ter mais de uma, desde que sigam esta ideia). Colocar "qualquer coisa que funcione" vai contra essa ideia. Além disso, as respostas  devem ser úteis para qualquer visitante futuro, o fato de também ajudar ao autor da pergunta é secundário e circunstancial (por mais contraditório que possa parecer)

Comment: @hkotsubo realmente totalmente contraditório: o fato de também ajudar ao autor da pergunta é secundário e circunstancial (por mais contraditório que possa parecer), não estou levando nem apoiando nem deixando de lado a idéia, mas, dizer isso também recorre no erro da funcionalidade do site.

Comment: Ou será que é porque essas pessoas dão respostas boas? Aqui é um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/498491/101. Pessoas que tem potencial não são teimosas. Eu quero o certo, não quero o errado, mesmo que seja plural. Agradeço por pelo menos dar sua opinião e assumir como pensa. Fico triste que alguém diga que não quer o certo, mas é um direito de qualquer um. Quem sabe anime outras pessoas dizerem o mesmo publicamente. Coloca no seu currículo essa frase em destaque. Embora a imagem não seja minha pode usar o mem dizendo que gosta do trabalho como nessa imagem. Tem quem goste também.

Comment: Algumas pessoas negativam justamente pessoas mais ativas no site sem negativar outras, isso é facilmente verificável porque quem é moderador. Porque as pessoas votam positivo não é. No exemplo que linkei acima tem negativos de pessoas que poderiam dizer qual é o erro da minha resposta. Não o fizeram porque não tem erro, ou votaram em retaliação ou não sabem porque estaria errado. Isso é tão ruim quanto positivarem respostas erradas que ensinam as pessoas seguir um rumo ruim. E por isso o mercado está cada vez mais com gente ruim trabalhando, elas são bombardeadas pelo errado por todo lado.

Comment: Pessoal o @Maniero chamou para comentar, quis expor a minha opinião, não quero polemizar não, se vcs quiserem eu apago.

Comment: @Danizavtz realmente só gera polêmica, por mais certo que o moderador esteja, só gera polêmica mas, ações concretas nenhuma porque o site não tem ferramentas mais aprimoradas para ajudar a comunidade, inclusive os mais antigos que tem resposta e experiências melhores que os novatos.

Comment: Não precisa apagar, a discussão é válida e acho que deve permanecer no site, assim se alguém tiver uma opinião parecida pode ver os contra argumentos (em vez de postar a mesma discussão novamente), e assim terá mais embasamento caso queira continuar

Comment: @hkotsubo eu entendo o seu ponto de vista, eu não quero "mudar" o consenso do site. Estou apenas expressando o meu ponto de vista de um usuário "novato" do site. Acho que vale a pena expor sua opinião tb.

Comment: Eu não ia me manifestar, mas visto uma informação que não é verídica preciso citar o meu caso ... Eu tenho 96k+, e quase todas minhas resps ganham em média +1 ~ +2, eu passo dias sem ganhar um misero ponto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento?tab=reputation, tem resps minhas que considero boas, que foram removidas pq não ganharam nenhum ponto e o autor também não se manifestou, teve uma resposta minha que foi melhor que todas do SOen sobre checar update na playstore, pq todas que encontrei lá eram usando uma gambiarra via HTTP para acessar a playstore web ...

Comment: ... a minha resposta no SOpt foi usando o que a documentação oficial sugere, eu tive só um "misero ponto", bom, então discordo disso de pessoas de score elevado ganharem +4 (em média), só ganha-se +4 quando a pergunta em si é boa e quando a resposta é excelente, e me perdoe, mas teve respostas suas que eu tive que palpitar apontando problemas, não técnicos, mas outros problemas que eram como questões de X & Y. Então você ganhar +1 ou as vezes tomar downvotes é mais provável que sejam por falhas em suas respostas. Me perdoe se pareci duro, não foi a intenção.

Comment: Vocês deveriam ver e entender, todos que se o site não mudar o jeito, nunca esses problemas serão solucionados, tudo é assim eu puxo a situação para um lado e fico criando fumaça e pouca ação coletiva, talvez os votos negativos na pergunta não quer dizer que não concorde com o moderador, mas, é uma manifestação onde as pessoas tem o site aberto e podem fazer qualquer pergunta e podem ser penalizados com fechamento e votos negativos e essas são as unicas ferramentas do site, o resto não adianta, porque os superiores e donos do site não querem qualidade eles querem quantidade ...

Comment: E o corporativismo?

Comment: @Danizavtz que corporativismo? Não somos parte da empresa, somos pessoas independentes, como eu disse, meu caso, eu sou uma pessoa que raramente ganha +1, tem resp minha que fica no 0 e no máximo só recebe o aceite. Tem resposta excelente minhas que são melhores (pois seguem o que é proposto por docs) que ganharam só 1 ponto. Bom, acho q terei q tentar virar funcionário da SO assim como os demais usuários que tem mais de 10k, será que estão contratando?

Comment: Cara, não estou falando da empresa SO estou falando da amizade e tal. Pessoas que tem empatia seu trabalho, por suas postagens, seu conhecimento esse tipo de coisa, não tem nada haver com ser empregado do stackoverflow.

Comment: @Todos vocês me inspiram a cada dia pelas respostas, pelo nível e pela humildade em responder as perguntas, isso também me motiva a fazer o meu melhor.

Comment: @novic Sobre a "funcionalidade do site", está no [Guia](/q/8045/112052): "*se a solução só ajuda a você, ela não é adequada para o site, já que a nossa premissa é ter soluções para várias pessoas, de modo que cada resposta deveria ajudar muitas pessoas e não só a você*". Enfim, isso que eu quis dizer com "secundário"

Comment: @Danizavtz o pessoal quer qualidade nas perguntas e nas respostas, não acho totalmente um corporativismo acho que é um ideologia que a muito tempo tentam seguir, para tonar o site referencia, o Guilherme disse bem ninguém é funcionário e moderadores não ganham nada, mas, tem a vontade de qualidade. É um assunto importante, mas, falta ao meu ver mudanças significativas no site e uma melhor regra no que é bom ou o que é ruim.

Comment: @Danizavtz "coleguismo" ou "cooperativismo"? Porque "corporativismo" dependeria de estarmos alinhados em algo e a única coisa que uns pouquissimos estão é em tornar o site um repositório de conhecimento (esse é o máximo de profissional/corporativo que dá para ser no site - já que não trabalhamos para SO).... Sobre "coleguismo", se você tem indícios fortes de fraude denuncie... Bom, sou colega de muita gente aqui e eles **não** andam votando nas minhas "respostas", porque quase sempre estou no 0 e 1, será que na verdade os usuários com mais de 10k são meus inimigos e se fingem de colegas?

Comment: @hkotsubo isso ai é um post do META, isso não muda nada é nesse ponto que eu estou dizendo, as coisas precisam mudar de cima para baixo e esses post no meta não muda nada!

Comment: Não estão atacando o problema maior que é dizer aos que representam o site que precisamos de melhores ferramentas e que as perguntas deveria também ficar numa lista de aprovação e que poderia ter uma medalhas para aprovação, não adianta colocar a culpa no usuário eles vão continuar fazendo errado se o site não os impede. A entrada de usuários é grande e os aspecto aumenta todos os dias, por isso das ferramentas

Comment: @Danizavtz Se está falando que as pessoa votam umas nas outras em forma de fraude isso é grave, faça uma reclamação formal e mostre os fatos. Caso contrário estará fazendo acusações falsas e isso chega ser crime. Se não é isso, esclareça melhor. E dê exemplo concreto para que todos posam ver do que está falando, se sua visão é real. Eu postei um exemplo concreto do problema.

Comment: @Danizavtz Não posso falar pelos demais, somente por mim: eu sempre voto no conteúdo e não na pessoa. O que acontece é que *geralmente* tem aqueles que costumam dar boas respostas na maioria das vezes, estão mais acostumados ao funcionamento do site e por isso erram menos e consequentemente ganham mais positivos (e aumentam sua pontuação), assim como há o oposto (aqueles que não entendem ou não querem participar adequadamente), e por isso tomam mais negativos. Eu não vejo corporativismo, pelo contrário, vejo distorção nos votos (coisa ruim ganhando +1 e coisas boas não sendo votadas)

Comment: Sobre regra do que é bom e ruim tem uma meia dúzia de postagens no META, incluindo  o "Guia de sobrevivência" ... então "regra clara" tem sim, e outra coisa eu disse e já expliquei, é o MCVE, muita resposta parece boa, mas é helpdesk em lugares aonde a PERGUNTA é totalmente relaxada, se for pra resolver perguntas relaxadas que não conseguem produzir um [mcve] então fica impossivel focar na qualidade, nos tornaremos um site de suporte técnico para atender pessoas gratuitamente. Muitos dos problemas esta em responder perguntas mal elaboradas e/ou ficar dando abertura pra isso.

Comment: Eu ensino as pessoas obterem mais votos: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4331/101. Em geral não querem fazê-lo. Alguns até criticaram, falaram que eu estava errado e depois reclamaram que não conseguem votos. Eu não mantive segredo do que funciona. É verdade que hoje não funciona bem como antes. Resposta boa, no assunto certo, na hora certa, sabendo valorizar dá votos, quando falta um desses elementos dá pouco, quando falta qualidade correção, aí dá o oposto.

Comment: *Eu quero uma resposta que funcione, não quero estar certo....*. Não é um concurso de popularidade, estamos demandando qualidade no conteúdo.  Ex: Essa resposta  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/463683/137387 é ótima e ponto final. Enquanto essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/500032/137387 é ineficiente, está bem escrita, tem um tom didático, resolve o problema mas tem complexidade de tempo O(n^2) somados ao equivoco de usar `System.getProperty("line.separator");` dentro de um laço. Funcionar não basta, temos que levar o melhor e não levar conteúdo errado quem está tentando aprender ou melhorar

Comment: *se o cara tem +10k rep (então eu dou +1, e esse cara recebe no mínimo 4)*, não é minha realidade eu tenho mais de 20% de respostas zeradas ganhei até uma [medalhinha da vergonha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious?userid=137387) só quando eu ganho uma pancada de votos numa resposta, tenho certeza na qualidade do conteúdo apresentado, contendo links, exemplo e resenha de documentação comprobatória, assim com no desempenho da solução dada. Pessoalmente sou uma cara chato, mas uns caras mais chatos do que eu ficavam pegando no meu pé quando comecei no site e isso só agregou.

Comment: Eu sou muito grato pelas discussões e votos negativos que me levaram a apagar conteúdo e remover comentários pois o que eu acreditava ser bom olho hoje e vejo esses conteúdos postados por mim como falhos e até danosos. E isso não agregou só no site o que eu aprendi aqui estou levando na minha vida.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu posso editar a pergunta criticada, mas não posso apagar é uma maneira diferente de resolver o problema, o código O(n^2) também está presente no código que foi positivado, única diferença que está fazendo em um string.join. (no caso a operação O(N^2) está na função join da string.

Comment: @Danizavtz Fico muito boa a edição da resposta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques vlw pela parceria.

Comment: @Danizavtz vc levantou bons pontos ai na sua resposta, mas um em particular achei mais interessante *"gostaria de uma comunidade plural"*. Não sei se entendi bem mas, ao meu ver, acho que falta aqui um pouco do que tem no SO em inglês, muitas respostas com diferentes soluções para uma mesma pergunta. Sei que a comunidade lá é bem maior e isso ajuda, mas tbm vejo muitas vezes o conceito de "certo/errado", que vc tbm comentou. As vezes uma resposta pode ser mais simples, nem sempre é preciso se escrever um artigo, o estado da arte, ou ter um snippet, codigo no ideone, etc

Comment: e continuando o comentário anterior, as vezes nós podemos estar desencorajando as pessoas. Veja, não estou dizendo pra aceitar qualquer coisa, mas até uma resposta com código apenas que funcione pode ser útil para muita gente, mesmo que a "qualidade" seja baixa. Sempre é melhor ter uma resposta com links, citações, explicação e na medida do possível, código, mas nem sempre todos fazem isso, e por diversas razões, e as vezes são boas respostas. Acho que ajuda mais comentar por exemplo "olha, isso está ruim" ou "coloque um exemplo" ou "comente essa linha" do que só negativar, e nem justificar

Comment: @RicardoPontual compartilho da mesma visão.

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual Não vou falar sobre a parte de encorajar ou desencorajar, não é sobre isso que estamos discutindo no tópico todo, então vou focar no que disse no primeiro comentário, ninguém falou de certo/errado no sentido de fazer respostas gigantes ou respostas curtas, não é nada disso o problema levantado, o problema são respostas erradas mesmo, coisas feitas no chute, e acredite, nos últimos tempos vi muita resposta de fato errada, teve gente que consegui conversar e teve gente que simplesmente ignorou, fora um ou outro que foi grosseiro.

Comment: Então o foco não é respostas excelente contra respostas rápidas, o foco é o problema de respostas que de fato estão erradas ou são causadoras de efeitos colaterais que quem chega no site e copia sem experiência não imagina. Não fui o único a me deparar com esse problema, então só para reiterar, o problema debatido na pergunta é sobre *"respostas erradas"*.

Comment: eu entendo @GuilhermeNascimento, o meu ponto é que sinto falta de respostas como aqui por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/57220  tem lá 9 respostas diferentes,  é ótimo encontrar perguntas assim, e acho que foi esse o ponto levantado na resposta por isso comentei, o que disse com "certo/errado" é que já vi muitos comentários nas respostas ou negativas por alguém por lá um simples `if` por exemplo, que não está errado, e as pessoas comentando **"isso tá erro, tem que tratar o erro, isso vai dar problema de injeção, de conversão, etc"** deveriamos tratar isso diferente :)

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual Tudo bem, mas o problema da comunidade não é esse, assim como também não é o problema discutido aqui, o problema é sobre as "respostas erradas", se acha que tem mérito discutir esse assunto recomendo que faça uma postagem exclusiva aqui no META mesmo. Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: acho que não vale a pena @GuilhermeNascimento era mesmo só pra completar esse ponto, e agradeço pelos comentários com ótimo ponto de vista :) sobre o foco principal da pergunta, concordo que devemos procurar responder coisas certas e com fundamento, outro dia mesmo respondi algo que não estava bom e removi depois de ser alertado :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim tem umas pessoas que ignoram, que preferem o erro mesmo depois de alertadas, teve caso que mesmo depois de receber negativos, de ter sido avisado, a pessoa insistiu que aquilo estava certo só porque funcionava em um situação específica, mesmo que em outras não funcionasse. É triste para a comunidade e para quem contrata os serviços desses pessoas já que fica tudo que ela faz como o Fiat 147. Mas é trágico quando essas coisas postadas aqui vão perpetuando o erro como se fosse certo. Esse nível de teimosia deveria ser inadmissível.

Comment: Tem nove negativos na pergunta que é o número de pessoas que eu fiz uma análise e faz isso no site atualmente, pode ser coincidência.