# O que mudou no entendimento de perguntas válidas no SOPt?

Tags: debate

O título da pergunta retrata uma situação que venho detectando ultimemente (ou nem tão ultimamente).

**Contexto**: todos tem notado um número absurdo de mensagens fechadas e/ou negativadas no site, se não tem, sugiro antes de continuar a ler isso, passar pela área de perguntas. Não vim aqui para criticar isso, eu mesmo voto para fechar em dezenas delas, e a grande maioria é porque os usuários não fazem o Tour ou não lêem sobre as diretivas do SOPt, que isso não é um forúm, coisa assim que já foram também exaustivamente abordadas em outras pergunta.

Meu ponto aqui é, o site não era assim há algum tempo atrás, e para embasar minha afirmação peguei algumas perguntas fechadas/avaliadas negativamente (novamente, não vou discutir se fechar estão "certo ou não", mas sim, o que mudou no entendimento) e pesquisei no site perguntas essencialmente parecidas, vou aqui definir para melhor entender como peguntas do tipo **"Como faço isso?"**.

É interessante notar que, há um tempo atrás essas perguntas eram respondidas e inclusive tem pontuação positiva, e hoje elas são fechadas, por isso, algo mudou na ideia do que é aceito, e gostaria de perceber melhor o que é.

Vamos há 2 exemplos:
[Upload de imagens e dados Strapi com Next JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/508634/upload-de-imagens-e-dados-strapi-com-next-js)

Nessa pergunta, que o título não ajuda, mas ao ler vou mudar para "Como fazer upload de imagens e dados Strapi com NextJS?" para melhor contextualizer. Há lá um exemplo do código e do retorno. Pergunta fechanda, score negativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vamos a essas outras perguntas mais antigas:

- [como-fazer-upload-de-imagens-usando-ckeditor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154184/como-fazer-upload-de-imagens-usando-ckeditor)
  [image: Relacionar o item]
- [como-fazer-upload-de-multiplas-imagens-com-apenas-1-click](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8257/como-fazer-upload-de-multiplas-imagens-com-apenas-1-click)
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- [como-fazer-upload-de-imagens-para-uma-pasta-usando-o-asp-cl%c3%a1ssico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5059/como-fazer-upload-de-imagens-para-uma-pasta-usando-o-asp-cl%C3%A1ssico)
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Elas tem a mesma "natureza" e "conceito" da primeira, inclusive umas nem código de exemplo tem, é uma pergunta champada de 1 linha sem contexto "Como fazer isso?", mas nenhuma delas está fechado ou tem score negativo, e tem respostas, o provavelmente hoje seria fechadas/negativadas.  Dai a pergunta:

**O que mudou no contexto do SOPt que justifique essa diferença?**

Sem analisar os pormenores das perguntas, apenas a nível de contexto, são comportamentos bem distintos.

Vamos a mais um exemplo: [como-trazer-em-colunas-diferentes-valores-da-mesma-coluna-de-uma-outra-tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/509189/como-trazer-em-colunas-diferentes-valores-da-mesma-coluna-de-uma-outra-tabela)

Essa outra é semelhante ao primeiro exemplo: "Como trazer....?", ela não está fechada(ainda), mas tem score negativo, ou seja, o entendimento é de que ela não é uma boa pergunta para a comunidade, ou não está de acordo com os objetivos do SOPt.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aí ok, mas vejam esses exemplos de perguntas "semelhantes":

- [Seria possível listar o enum de um campo de uma tabela através de uma query?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383779/seria-poss%C3%ADvel-listar-o-enum-de-um-campo-de-uma-tabela-atrav%C3%A9s-de-uma-query)
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- [Select trazendo todos os registros não duplicados baseados em uma unica coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/395585/select-trazendo-todos-os-registros-n%C3%A3o-duplicados-baseados-em-uma-unica-coluna)
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

São essencialmente perguntas semelhantes, de novo, sem analisar os pormenores, mas em contexto são semelhantes: "Como fazer ....?", mas tem entendimento bem diferente da comunidade.

A ideia não é discutir em particular cada pergunta, mas novamente, como contexto, o que há de diferente no entendimento da comunidade quando as mais antigas foram analisadas e "aceitas" por assim dizer, e essas mais recentes?

Deixo aqui mais dois pares de perguntas semelhantes, atual/antiga caso alguém queira ver como exemplos:

- [Separação algarismo de um tipo int em C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/509165/separa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-algarismo-de-um-tipo-int-em-c)  e [Dividir números de um int. C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179098/dividir-n%C3%BAmeros-de-um-int-c)
- [Como Faço para definir o valor das celulas com o XSSFCell para exportar para o Excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/509066/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-definir-o-valor-das-celulas-com-o-xssfcell-para-exportar-para-o-e) e [Exportar tabela HTML para Excel mantendo os estilos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275364/exportar-tabela-html-para-excel-mantendo-os-estilos)

Obs: desculpem as imagens, mas ajuda a manter o histórico no momento dessa pergunta e pra visualização de todos.

Comment: Eu tive essa dúvida quando analisei algumas perguntas antigas que tinham altos _upvotes_. Se fosse o fator tempo, eu até entenderia, porque a qualidade do site evoluiu com os anos (creio eu). Veja essa pergunta [Como faço para remover acentos em uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string), hoje em dia é muito provável que ela seria fechada, mas olhe a data da postagem... O mesmo vale para algumas resposta (que não lembro onde vi) com muitos votos que ainda foram favoritadas mesmo parecendo que foram copiadas e coladas literalmente.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, eu entendi o que você quis dizer, mas não acho que a qualidade do site esteja aumentando. Pelo menos da forma como julgo, a qualidade do site está _diminuindo_ porque tem muita gente fazendo pergunta mal elaborada para poucas pessoas "curarem" o conteúdo. O que aumenta é a qualidade e rigor da curadoria que poucos aqui fazem. Eu também questiono alguns fechamentos, mas é melhor do que manter um monte de coisa ("ruim" - para o ponto de vista do que este site espera) aberta.

Comment: @LuizFelipe *qualidade da moderação. Isso é verdade, eu que nem era de fazer muita pergunta, passei a contribuir mais com perguntas porque é triste abrir o feed perguntas novas e elas serem em grande maioria de baixa qualidade e que estão relacionada a problemas individuais que dificilmente ajudariam outros devs...

Comment: @CmteCardeal essa pergunta que você linkou foi ótima para analisar isso, ela com certeza hoje estaria e fechada e nunca teria 71 **votos somente positivos**. De novo como coloquei na pergunta, não estou dizendo se está "certo ou errado", "melhor ou pior", mas é entender o conceito e para onde estamos indo, isso ajuda até a entender melhor. Nós que estamos a mais tempo aqui entendemos melhor isso, mas um usuário novo que chega e sua pergunta é fechada e pontuada negativa e olha essa outra, o que ele vai pensar? por isso acho legal ter esse dabate e poder explicar o que mudou

Comment: Em relação à pergunta colocada pelo @CmteCardeal, embora alguns aqui possam concordar que deveria ser fechada (e eu também, de fato, acho que seria fechada), eu acredito que não é o tipo de pergunta que _deveria_ ser fechada. Bom, é uma pergunta do tipo "como faço isso" (aka. "faz pra mim"), mas que, pelo menos da forma como vejo, tem uma utilidade para outras pessoas. Tipo [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/496644/69296), mais recente e fechada. Vai da opinião, né... Eu sou contra perguntas mal feitas, mas não contra perguntas que, embora sejam o típico "faz pra mim", possam ajudar outros.

Comment: @LuizFelipe esse ponto que você levantou sobre a qualidade é algo que penso ser essa tendência: há um tempo atrás talvez não tivesse tanto conteúdo mais, digamos "básico", e a medida que isso tem em abundancia e fácil de encontrar na internet, o SOPt assumiu uma postura mais criteriosa, presando por algo que talvez "não se encontre por ai", o que eu acho bom e diferencia o site, eu só queria perceber se  mais alguém tem esse entendimento, ou outras ideias :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual _", o SOPt assumiu uma postura mais criteriosa, presando por algo que talvez "não se encontre por ai""_ eu acho que não. Pode ser aquele caso de "novidade no SOpt", por exemplo uma pergunta que nunca foi feita, mas pode ser uma ótima opção de consulta. Por exemplo esta minha pergunta [O que é BFF (Back-end For Front-end)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/507893/o-que-%c3%a9-bff-back-end-for-front-end) é uma pergunta fácil de se encontrar a reposta, mas como nunca foi abordada no SOpt (diretamente), eu achei que seria útil para o site, postá-la! e ainda teve bons up.

Comment: Vou pegar um gancho no comentário do @LuizFelipe, sobre a pergunta "ser útil para a comunidade", e vou pegar uma fresquinha, que acabou de ser fechada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/509235/57220  o título seria um candidato a "servir para a comunidade": "De que forma posso pegar dados de um JS e disponibilizar via PHP", mas ao entrar na pergunta, é um problema bem específico e uma situação particular do código "Porque a variável $variavelphp não retornar nada no echo?", ou seja, um fechamento perfeito, um "analisa pra mim" , ela não seria útil para a maioria da comunidade

Comment: @CmteCardeal esse seu exemplo é ótimo, pq sua pergunta cai num outro conceito que até já foi abordado aqui, o de "não ter uma resposta em português". Ela pode ser encontrada na internet, mas talvez não em português, e não no conceito do SOPt, talvez se encontre um artigo, mas não uma resposta mais "objetiva", por isso acho ela super pertinente ao site, mas é um bom ponto esse que levantou, faz sentido

Comment: É no conhecimento das regras de funcionamento do site, ou no desconhecimento delas, que o daemon de Maxwell faz morada. O site não se trata só de fechar perguntas, mas também trata-se também de reabri-las. O usuários ou tentam reabrir no grito ou replicam diversas vezes a pergunta ou fazem edições irrelevantes para a manter no topo da home esperando pescar um comentário milagroso ou diversas contas para flodar o mesmo conteúdo. Ou seja muitos usuários novatos nos tomam por nerds tolos usam de truques bobos o que endurece a ótica de quem está analisando a qualidade das perguntas.

Comment: complementando: então muita coisa que pode vir a ser boa passa batido.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não sei o que o pessoal pensa, mas com certeza por não fazer o tour e ler as regras muita gente pensa que é um fórum, pra postar qq pergunta, perdir pra fazer debug, análise de código, ou trabalho de casa. É difícil ao analisar uma pergunta ver se ela mesmo não sendo bem escrita ou com bons critérios de qualidade, se vale a pena ser respondida pq vai trazer benefício para muitas pessoas. Por exemplo "Como fazer download em linguagem X?" é diferente "Por que no meu código não consigo fazer download em linguagem X?", na dúvida a gente costuma fechar e pede pra dar detalhes

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPt

Comment: @LuizFelipe sobre essa questão do array, eu concordo que ela tem um valor, __o problema nesse caso está em como ela foi feita__. Parece que o AP não se esforçou um mínimo se quer para elaborar esta pergunta, e nesse caso ela pode ser avaliada como baixa qualidade. O mesmo vale pra pergunta do C#. Se na minha pergunta sobre BFF eu chegasse e escrevesse: _"`[title]: O que é BFF?` nunca ouvir falar, o que é?"_ só isso, é capaz de um ter tomado mais de 1 downvote e ter a pergunta fechada. Mas não! Eu pensei em como elaborar uma pergunta criativa que também despertasse a curiosidade de quem leu.

Comment: Uma coisa que talvez alguns não sabem é que para novatos o processo de perguntar agora é bem mais complexo, o cara tem que ignorar bem o que lhe é instruído para fazer a bobagem que faz.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, eu entendo, mas ali é um caso extremamente simples, então qualquer desenvolvimento a mais só ia ser ruído. Para esse tipo de questão, extremamente pontual, detalhar ao extremo acaba prejudicando com coisa desnecessária. Mas eu de fato entendo quem argumenta pelo fechamento. De todo modo, o AP daquela pergunta nem existe mais. Convido-o, então, com as melhores intenções, a tentar melhorá-la via edição. Eu tentei, mas não sei como melhorá-la ao ponto de ainda manter a sutileza. Talvez seja realmente um problema intrínseco da pergunta que eu (ainda) não consigo ver.

Comment: @LuizFelipe bora.. vou editar e me diz o que você acha. Se você analisar esta pergunta, ela parece uma questão de trabalho de faculdade/escola que alguém copiou e colou no site. Mas pela sua resposta, a pergunta tem um valor porque abordar diferentes maneiras de se chegar a um mesmo resultado. Isso que é incrível na programação. Não existe uma única solução para muitas coisas, e um pouco de tempero só tem a expandir o conhecimento de quem quer aprender...

Comment: Só pra constar, tem muita pergunta antiga, inclusive algumas com resposta minha com accept e tudo, que hoje eu fecho quando esbarro. Tem que lembrar que teve uma fase que houve uma tentativa de abrir o escopo e tolerar certas coisas pra ver se dava certo e não deu. Foi meio que uma "sugestão administrativa" na época. Tanto que muito do que acho duvidoso dessa época, que hoje eu negativaria, evito negativar pq sei que o contexto era outro, só que não posso deixar aberto só por isso. Negativo e fechamento são coisas de naturezas diferentes, mas se foi fechado, problema sanado, cabe uma "canja".

Comment: @Bacco legal saber, isso tbm contextualiza muito e da pra entender mais como era antes

Comment: @RicardoPontual inclusive, até pedimos um [Super User em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=super+user) para atendermos a parte de "suporte" de TI que tem demanda mas não cabe aqui. A proposta estava indo bem, mas a SE fechou, alegando que não era momento de outro site internacional. Eu não achei muito válido o argumento pq ia ser quase identico à estrutura daqui, tradução e tudo o mais, não era "qualquer site" e sim um de tema próximo, inclusive com muitos dos mesmos users dispostos a participar em ambos. Mas a empresa é soberana, afinal, a rede é propriedade deles.

Comment: Nem sabia disso, estava vendo o posto sobre o fechamento e fui meio "tenso" por assim dizer.  Enfim há muita coisa na história do SOPt. Aliás, já off-topic mas curioso, por conta disso pensei "olha tem muita gente que fala lingua portuguesa, é preciso se atentar nisso" e fui pesquisar sobre isso.. não há uma informação concensual, mas o link que tem cálculos mais aproximados, conta algo em torno de 250 milhões de pessoas: https://www.tsf.pt/opiniao/realisticamente-quantos-sao-os-falantes-de-portugues-no-mundo-11404078.html

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas o Maniero foi mais rápido. Concordo com tudo que ele disse. Resumindo minha posição, não mudou nada no entendimento, até porque nunca houve consenso sobre essas perguntas na comunidade, nem entre os moderadores. Ou melhor, existe um consenso tácito entre os moderadores de que muitas dessas perguntas poderiam ser salvas, se tivesse gente interessada em salvar. Várias acabam fechadas por ser o caminho mais fácil de manter o site organizado, dado o volume de perguntas problemáticas e a pouca intervenção da comunidade nelas.

Answer (score 7):

O resumo de tudo isso é que no passado a relação sinal/ruído era diferente e a comunidade existia de fato.

Tinha pouca coisa com problema e muita que era legal. Então mesmo as ruins dava para trabalhar, principalmente porque as pessoas que apareciam tinham um pouco mais de condições de melhorar (e já reclamávamos disso na época, agora ficou insustentável). Hoje grande parte das pessoas que fazem as perguntas são analfabetos funcionais. Lamento dizer isso, mas não fui eu que os tornei assim. E você percebe até mesmo na primeira postagem da pessoa que não vai pra frente. Até aí tudo bem.

O problema é que foi tendo mais ruído que sinal, passou a ter muita dificuldade de salvar algo. E pra "ajudar" as pessoas que mais ajudavam, dando boas respostas, editando as perguntas, comentando para fazer a pergunta melhor, foram sumindo.

Sobraram algumas pessoas que atuam na comunidade, mas acumulou muito problema para essas pessoas resolverem, não dá para gastar tempo com algo que provavelmente não vai se salvar. Ainda tem algumas pessoas que não conseguem tirar algo das pessoas que perguntam, seja por culpa dos APs, mas também pode ser problema de um membro ativo da comunidade que não tem a habilidade ou o conhecimento necessário para salvar. Inclusive alguns membros respondem coisas que não dava pra responder, depois se arrependem, em geral essas pessoas são um pouco ingênuas até no conhecimento da computação, e não é incomum as respostas serem ruins.

E aí vem outro motivo, quando se deixa aberto algo mais ou menos ruim, que antes seria melhorada e receberia uma resposta boa, hoje é quase certo que ficará ruim e receberá uma resposta ruim que se perpetuará e ensinará as pessoas de forma equivocada. Então também é culpa de quem responde, fazê-lo melhor. Se houvesse mais compromisso talvez desse para deixar mais coisas abertas. E isso se torna um problema quando ocorre de um membro ativo e que fica repetidas vezes fazendo isso. Já falei disso em [Por que as pessoas precisam responder o que não sabem ou o que não ajuda corretamente?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8573/101). Reforçando, se as pessoas respondessem melhor e selecionassem mais o que responder, e quem sabe ajudassem mais a salvar a pergunta antes de responder, poderíamos deixar mais coisas abertas.

Além disso no começo estávamos vendo o que funcionava ou não. E descobrimos que algumas coisas não funcionavam. Algumas até funcionavam, mas não funcionam mais pelos motivos que eu disse acima. E no começo era interessante termos algumas perguntas mais genéricas, agora é tudo repetição ou ajuda muito específica, só uma variação do que de fato já foi respondido. Então sim, mudou um pouco ao longo de tempo conforme várias discussões que foram tendo.

E no passado muita gente votava, muita mesmo. E claro que tudo tinha mais voto. Embora o voto sempre foi mal usado. As pessoas não gostam muito de dar negativo (tem usuário que dá pouco e dá em alguns casos concentrado em um usuário porque não gosta dele) e votam positivo como se fosse um *like* para dizer "também quero saber disso", mesmo que a pergunta seja ruim.

E vou admitir que a quantidade de ruído faz tudo piorar, inclusive a moderação, da comunidade ou diamante. Não só pelo volume, mas é desgastante ter que lidar com tanto problema, é difícil querer ser uma ilha de excelência num mar de problemas. Volto a dizer, se a comunidade fosse mais atuante dava pra fazer uma avaliação melhor. Só que hoje tem tanto problema que a comunidade precisaria ser maior do que era há 5 ou 6 anos.

E lembrei de algo importante. Já vi pessoas acusando que a comunidade trata diferente as pessoas. E é fato. Existe uma diferença entre você ver algo de alguém comprometido com a comunidade, que você sabe que vai ajudar se tiver um problema, que fará o que precisa ser feito, que está fazendo aquilo pensando na comunidade, e quem só veio porque está desesperado e quer uma solução para o **seu** problema, que não liga pro site, pra qualidade dele, ou qualquer aspecto que ajude outras pessoas. Essas pessoas não são maravilhosas e coitadinhas, elas só usam os outros sem dar em troca o mínimo de consideração para que as pessoas a ajudem, nem falo de nada mais intenso.

E eu vou lembrando outras coisas. As pessoas passaram ter atitudes ruins no site que ajudam fortalecer a necessidade de fechamentos, entre elas a repetição de perguntas fechadas. Só pegando esse exemplo, era algo que não acontecia, outras coisas também não, as pessoas passaram a ser desonestas e querem burlar os acontecimentos em vez de resolver os problemas. Isso deve ser alguma consequência do que que acontece na sociedade, não é possível que sair de praticamente zero casos por dia para dezenas diários pelo menos em alguns dias. A atitude das pessoas chamam mais pelo fechamento.

Outro ponto importante é que ter alguma pergunta aberta nunca será justificativa para não fechar outras. É como falar pro guarda que você não deve levar multa porque acabou de passar um cara correndo mais que você. Ou que você pode ser corrupto porque os políticos não são presos por isso.

Mais do que isso eu não consigo responder porque foi acontecendo organicamente, não teve uma virada de chave específica.

## Exemplos

[Veja como estava a pergunta que foi fechada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/508634/1). Não que melhorou muito com a edição. Tem informação suficiente para responder? Então leia os parágrafos anteriores porque as perguntas precisam ser fechadas logo. Uma resposta seria dada por quem acha que dá para responder isso. Essa pergunta poderia ser fechada por vários motivos, a pessoa só quer uma ajuda genérica. Tem mais que um pedido de ajuda inclusive. E a formatação não ajuda, embora isso por si só não seja motivo para fechamento. Ninguém foi lá arrumar nem isso. Ninguém comentou pra ver se consegue salvar. Se não houve esforço para salvar era para ter fechado mesmo.

Obrigado por indicar algumas perguntas para fechar. Ainda que algumas contenham boas respostas. Coisa que raramente acontece em casos assim hoje em dia. Alguns talvez até para manter a coerência.

Olhando por cima não vi grandes problemas em [Como trazer, em colunas diferentes, valores da mesma coluna de uma outra tabela, com condições diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/509189/101). Mas entendo os negativos. A pergunta está feita de qualquer jeito, parece jogada, parece que a pessoa não está muito preocupada com nada. O título já é a pergunta, mas demora pra perceber. E aí vem um "preciso algo mais ou menos assim", o que dá depois dá a entender que é um "agora se vira pra fazer pra mim". E de fato a resposta deu 2 opções, e poderiam ser outras porque a pergunta não tem muito detalhe. Deu vontade de fechar, ficou quase um enunciado sem muitos detalhes e não sei se a resposta é boa (algumas pessoas acharão que é, mas será que é?).

Os exemplos antigos parecem ter alguns problemas, mas pelo menos um dele nem tanto. Eu não sei bem, SQL não é um assunto que eu domino tanto então é mais complicado eu tomar uma decisão, eu tendo a deixar mais coisas abertas sobre isso, ainda que sejam ruins. Eu sei quando algo é bem ruim, sei quando tem erros grosseiros e merecem pelo menos negativo. Outras pessoas podem pensar diferente por entender mais que eu do assunto.

A pergunta sobre soma de dígitos em C++ antiga dá para entender oque precisa, a nova não dá para entender a confusão que passa na cabeça da pessoa, talvez seja simples, mas por que ela escreveu algo tão confuso então?

As de Java não parecem boas, mas não parei para avaliar melhor, então não posso tomar uma ação.

Tem exemplos até nos comentários, que no fundo é a dup da dup da dup. E pra falar a verdade ficou tão complicado achar que é fica mais fácil fechar por outro motivo, ainda que não ajude tanto o AP ali. E o fato da duplicata travar a pergunta para remoção e quase sempre o texto ali não ajuda ser melhor achada, também chega ser quase abusivo marcar como duplicata.

E vejo muitos fechamentos por motivos errados (de acordo com minha concepção), mas hoje em dia me preocupo mais em estar fechado do que o motivo certo (não deveria ser o ideal, mas não estamos em situação ideal em vários aspectos). Inclusive hoje vejo uma certa preguiça em pensar e usam o fechamento coringa de "fora de escopo porque não é um problema específico").

Aliás, a criação desse motivo pode explicar um pouco o aumento de fechamentos. Eu o criei para ser um coringa mesmo, mas não acho que deveria ser tão usado assim. Ele deveria ser o antigo motivo "muito específico", que é o que conhecemos como "faz pra mim".

E admito que tem hora que "se a pessoa não se esforçou" por que eu deveria gastar minutos analisando para fechar pelo motivo mais certo, sendo que isso não levará a lugar algum?

A comunidade atuante de forma adequada pode ajudar isso acontecer menos. É cansativo.

Vou destacar este comentário: [O que mudou no entendimento de perguntas válidas no SOPt?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8596/o-que-mudou-no-entendimento-de-perguntas-v%c3%a1lidas-no-sopt#comment35516_8596).

Há uma dissonância entre o que os perguntadores e o respondedores querem, na maior parte dos casos, tem exceções como essa. Quem precisa de "ajuda" que se adapte a quem vai ajudar, não o contrário. Eu sei que algumas pessoas querem inverter, mas o mundo sempre foi assim, torne seu assunto desejável para os outros, não ache que os outros possuem obrigações com você. E no SOpt não pode-se oferecer dinheiro, que, na quantia certa de acordo com a qualidade, seria uma forma de tornar seu interesse desejável.

## Conclusão

Como está qualidade do site? Aumentando ou diminuindo? Essa é a questão. Ou fazemos o que tem que ser feito para não deixar a qualidade cair cada vez mais ou abandonamos tudo e deixamos vira uma porcaria qualquer cheio de perguntas e respostas ruins, que só ajudam a pessoa, que não tem nem pé nem cabeça, com respostas sem sentido, erradas, ou enganosas que até podem resolver o ponto específico mas causa outro problema e que outras pessoas incautas vão assumir como algo bom porque ouviram falar que o Stack Overflow é bom.

A questão é mais complexa, mas eu não tenho mais a mesma paciência para explicar com todos detalhes que precisaria, até porque seria um resumo do que eu já disse em diversas postagens no meta.

De qualquer forma ainda esse ano devo fazer uma postagem alertando para que o SO (pt ou en) não é mais bom como era antes, que coisas antigas são mais confiáveis e que agora não devemos confiar no conteúdo novo. E aí posso deixar o site virar a porcaria que alguns querem.

Comment: *"porque foi acontecendo organicamente, não teve uma virada de chave específica."* esse ponto já resume porque é difícil notar como aconteceu, pq na verdade é uma soma de fatores que tem na resposta e outros que foram moldando o entendimento com o tempo. Mas o fator mais importante talvez seja o que menciou, que a comunidade cresceu demais, e ficou difícil cuidar dessas perguntas do jeito que era no passado, é muita pergunta pra pouca gente resolver, e isso é uma realidade.