# Como posso melhorar uma pergunta que não é minha?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Não sou um antigo do Stack Overflow em Português, então não sei como eram as coisas aqui há mais de dois anos, mas eventualmente vejo, aqui no meta, depoimentos de usuários antigos que acabam mencionando uma maior participação geral da "comunidade antiga". Entre essa *maior* participação, amiúde vejo que existia uma maior preocupação com a **melhoria de perguntas** pelo site.

Embora essa prática de melhorar perguntas pareça já ter sido relativamente recorrente por aqui, é algo que raramente vejo ocorrer por aqui.

O que vejo é que muitos usuários novatos vêm ao site com uma pergunta mal feita por não saberem como redigir uma boa questão. Mas às vezes a "dúvida", ou o pedido de "faz para mim", *pode* ter um valor que justifique uma melhoria por parte da comunidade.

Então pode haver casos nos quais um membro da comunidade queira melhorar uma pergunta que realmente tenha um valor escondido. Nesse tipo de situação, o que deve ser feito?

- É de interesse da comunidade a melhoria de perguntas mal feitas, mas com um "bom valor"?
- Como essa melhoria de perguntas pode ser abordada? O membro pode *editar* a pergunta que não o pertence?
- Se a pergunta a ser melhorada estiver fechada, a comunidade engajaria em um processo de reabertura? Ou o processo de melhoria seria jogado fora?
- Se editar a pergunta não for uma opção, um outro usuário pode refazer e postar essa pergunta com uma qualidade melhor e mais bem elaborada, que possa trazer valor para comunidade?

---

O problema de qualidade que vemos aqui no SOpt deve-se, principalmente, ao fato de muitos novatos não terem a técnica de como se redigir uma boa pergunta. E, claro, não têm também a devida paciência para ler os vários documentos do meta que explicam o tipo de questão que desejamos por aqui. Embora essa "preguiça" *não* seja um comportamento ideal (da sociedade mesmo), temos que aceitar: é a triste realidade.

Vejo, com isso, um outro possível potencial positivo às melhorias de pergunta:

- Além de, claro, possibilitar uma melhoria na qualidade de perguntas aqui no site,
- As melhorias podem servir de exemplo prático para que o autor da pergunta original entenda, de fato, o tipo de pergunta que se deseja por aqui. Com um comparativo nítido antes *versus* depois, esse tipo de entendimento *pode* se tornar mais nítido.

---

Não estou fazendo essas perguntas para "forçar" a comunidade a fazer isso. Já temos muito trabalho só com o *fechamento* de perguntas mal feitas. Melhorar a qualidade das "reaproveitáveis" será só mais um fardo para a comunidade.

A pergunta está aqui para ser mais um guia de *se isso **deve** ser feito* e **como** se fazer.

Acho que seria valioso debatermos sobre isso.

Comment: EU ia perguntar isso kkkkkkk. Até tinha desfeito minha edição daquela pergunta do array.

Comment: Acho que poderiamos perguntar, também, se editar não for uma opção, alguém refazer e postar essa pergunta com uma qualidade melhor. Talvez não seja bem visto, mas vale o questionamento...

Comment: Eu acho isso meio estranho, mas de fato vale o questionamento.

Comment: Complicou, eu consigo responder uma parte, outra não, até porque beira a ser ampla, que é o título.

Comment: @Maniero, deve dar para diminuir então. O que a aproxima do "amplo"?

Comment: "Como posso melhorar uma pergunta que não é minha?" Sem um exemplo concreto eu difícil falar sobre isso, é subjetivo, tem vários "dependes", não é objetivo como as outras. Não digo que não dê para responder, mas pra ser bom será longo, tentando abordar tudo, eu não sou a melhor pessoa para fazer isso, nem tenho mais a mesma paciência de antes.

Comment: A ideia era ser mais generalista mesmo, para meio que servir como um "faq" para o que fazer quando eu achar que posso melhorar uma pergunta que não é minha. De todo modo, eu entendo o "amplo" que você mencionou, @Maniero.

Comment: @LuizFelipe acho que o título poderia ser: _"O quanto eu posso tentar para melhorar uma pergunta de baixa qualidade/fechada?"_

Comment: Acho que continua no mesmo nível de amplitude. O jeito é deixar e ver o debate que dá. Se tiver certa comoção da comunidade, aí sim pode-se justificar uma resposta para dar um pouco mais de formalismo à matéria. cc: @CmteCardeal

Comment: O problema maior é que antes de tudo tem que entender o que o autor da tal pergunta quer. Geralmente é melhor ajudar o autor a melhorar a pergunta. Uma vez que esteja tudo muito claro, aí dá pra "otimizar" melhorando exemplos, simplificando texto, reestruturando a ordem das coisas. Perguntas que tem como ter salvas sem grande complicação normalmente nem fechadas são (a gente arruma na hora).

Comment: O que tem que realmente tomar cuidado é de não tentar "salvar resposta que supostamente é boa" sob pretexto de estar salvando a pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco em uma discussão [nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8596/o-que-mudou-no-entendimento-de-perguntas-v%c3%a1lidas-no-sopt), tinhamos a intenção de tentar melhorar uma pergunta, só que no caso o AP nem existe mais no sistema.  Ai eu acho que complica um pouco...  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496644/como-deixar-um-array-vazio-apagar-todos-os-elementos-em-javascript

Comment: @CmteCardeal serve como exemplo do que eu disse há pouco, aí é tentativa de salvar resposta, e não pergunta. Melhor, no meu ver, é investir a energia de responder em pergunta mais elaborada. Inclusive, tem fortes indicativos de que a pergunta é um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70)

Comment: boa pergunta, eu costumo quando edito evitar interferir o máximo no conteúdo, eu formato código sempre, e quanto é html/css/js tento por no snippet, mas é interessante pensar, se é possível por exemplo acrescentar coisas que não descaracterizem a pergunta

Answer (score 11):

Vou responder oque eu consigo, quem sabe outros respondam o que é a pergunta principal.

> É de interesse da comunidade a melhoria de perguntas mal feitas, mas com um "bom valor"?

Sim, sempre foi e continua sendo. Esse é o objetivo do site e as ferramentas ajudam (poderiam ajudar mais) que isso aconteça. A filosofia é que devemos criar conteúdo de qualidade, a forma exata não importa muito, desde que não crie outros problemas.

Só não acontece mais porque as pessoas não querem, não sabem, ou não conseguem fazê-lo. Já aconteceu mais.

> O membro pode editar a pergunta que não o pertence?

Totalmente, a ideia é essa. Se ela é capaz de melhorar, deve fazê-lo. Nem que dê problemas com o AP, e deu nos exemplos abaixo, por isso perguntas novas foram criadas. Claro que é preciso bom senso.

> Se a pergunta a ser melhorada estiver fechada, a comunidade engajaria em um processo de reabertura? Ou o processo de melhoria seria jogado fora?

Não sei, não é tão simples, é um risco, mas se a pessoa souber fazer ela consegue engajamento de uma forma ou de outra. Pode ser jogado fora. Se a pessoa investir onde compensa acho que pode ser sucesso.

Antes eu gostaria que as pessoas pensassem nisso: [Devemos editar uma pergunta que está/será fechada e possivelmente removida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7946/101). Boa parte das perguntas que vão para a fila de reabertura possuem edições irrelevantes por um motivo ou outro. Pode até resolver um problema, mas não o que faria a pergunta ser reaberta, então ela vai pro lixo e o trabalho de edição e de análise foi desperdiçado.

Quero que as pessoas invistam nisso (sem exigir, já deixei claro em várias postagens que as pessoas não devem fazer nada que não estejam dispostas), mas devem fazer algo certo, se começar ter edições que não trazem vantagem, acho perda de tempo da pessoa e mais trabalho para o resto da comunidade.

Vejam os comentários acima que o Bacco postou.

> Se editar a pergunta não for uma opção, um outro usuário pode refazer e postar essa pergunta com uma qualidade melhor e mais bem elaborada, que possa trazer valor para comunidade?

Eu mesmo já fiz perguntas novas quando a original era ruim e o AP não queria colaborar, em geral funciona melhor com assuntos conceituais: [O tamanho de uma função afeta a performance e consumo de memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31485/101). Também: [Como gerar sequências numéricas em SQL sem precisar criar tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33859/101) (que funciona porque era certo que seria bem respondida, [vide outra resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8599/101)). Acho que as perguntas originais não existem mais.

Note que isso tende ser exceção, mas não precisa ser. E já recentemente outras pessoas fazendo algo nesse sentido.

> O problema de qualidade que vemos aqui no SOpt deve-se, principalmente, ao fato de muitos novatos não terem a técnica de como se redigir uma boa pergunta

Concordo em parte. Muitas vezes é um problema de falta de noção geral, preguiça e até falta de caráter porque eles descumprem regras deliberadamente, ignoram tudo o que é passado, até durante a escrita da pergunta, sem falar que não olha o ambiente primeiro, a pessoa chega e mete o pé na porta. Mas de fato tem casos que se redigir melhor salva.

> essa "preguiça" não seja um comportamento ideal (da sociedade mesmo), temos que aceitar: é a triste realidade

Isso eu não concordo, acho que não devemos aceitar. É a minha opinião.

> As melhorias podem servir de exemplo prático para que o autor da pergunta original entenda, de fato, o tipo de pergunta que se deseja por aqui. Com um comparativo nítido antes versus depois, esse tipo de entendimento pode se tornar mais nítido

Infelizmente se isso fosse verdade nunca teria piorado, porque no começo as pessoas se dedicavam e tinha muito exemplo bom. As pessoas não olham nem os bons, nem os maus exemplos, elas só mandam bala pensando (de forma pouco inteligente) em si.

Para ajudar as pessoas poderiam colocar os *links* da [help] ou as postagens que tem no meta que mostram como melhorar a pergunta, por exemplo o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101). Eu fiz várias, cada uma pode servir em um contexto. Eu sei que as pessoas não vão ler, e por isso provavelmente a maioria nem se preocupa em postaram eu mesmo não faço por isso, então não cobro que as pessoas façam, mas se quiser ajudar pode ser uma boa. Quanto mais você se dedicar a ajudar mais a chance de dar resultado. Você avalia o que compensa para você. Pra mim não compensa mais ajudar a maioria dos casos.

Outras boas:

- [Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8388/101)
- [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)
- [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/101)
- [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/101)
- [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/101)
- [Minha pergunta foi fechada, não posso obter uma resposta ali?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7928/101)

E tem os comentários enlatados que ajuda> [Comentários enlatados para situações comuns](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/707/101).

Comment: Quanto à penúltima parte, talvez tenha me expressado mal. Não quis dizer que temos que aceitar a preguiça aqui no site, mas sim aceitar que ela existe (e, de fato, parece-me um problema bem recorrente por aqui). Sobre a aceitar a preguiça aqui no site, idealmente, não mesmo. E em relação à última, sou obrigado a concordar – é verdade. Talvez tenha sido um pingo de falsa esperança. :D Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Analisando a resposta do Maniero, acha que vale a pena, nesse caso, __eu repostar a mesma pergunta__ só que mais elaborada? Porque você já tens bons upvotes na sua resposta atual...

Comment: @CmteCardeal, não sei responder isso; mas penso que, como já tem uma resposta, poderia ser meio que vista como uma "duplicata". Ainda sou a favor de tentar _melhorar_ a pergunta, apesar de achar que já está boa. Não acho que "encher linguiça" para "criar contexto" iria a melhorar (penso que só iria a piorar, adicionando ruído). Mas claro, é a minha opinião. /// De todo modo, a minha ideia com esta discussão no meta era ser mais generalista, e não discutir perguntas específicas como essa. Talvez até por essa tentativa de generalizar tenha ficado meio amplo.

Comment: @LuizFelipe se vc deletar a resposta e repostar em outra pergunta, não é mais duplicata, pq aquela vai passar a não ter resposta (em casos que tiver só 1 resposta, claro).

Comment: @Bacco, eu acho que isso daria mais trabalho do que tentar melhorar a pergunta que já existe. E, tendo em vista que o resultado final seria quase que o mesmo, não vejo compensação pelo esforço maior. Você está sugerindo o contrário?

Comment: @LuizFelipe não estou sugerindo nada. Só disse que pra ser duplicata, tem que ter resposta, entao se tira a resposta, deixa de correr o risco de fechar por duplicata. Sobre melhorar pergunta que existe, para isso tem que garantir que vai manter intenção do autor (o que geralmente é impossivel sem interferència deste).