# "Seguir" uma pergunta para oferecer recompensa quando possível

Tags: novo-recurso

Eu entendo que a gente não pode oferecer recompensas em perguntas novas, por diversos motivos. Evitar dar recompensas por impulso, dar tempo à comunidade para oferecer boas respostas etc.

O que eu gostaria de pedir não é que o prazo de dois dias seja reduzido. Eu gostaria de ter alguma forma de ser notificado que aquela pergunta legal, supimpa, última-coca-cola-do-deserto me avisasse na hora em que pudesse receber uma recompensa.

Eu vejo perguntas excelentes de vez em quando, mas que não recebem a atenção que merecem. Eu adoraria dar recompensas em várias delas. Mas infelizmente minha cabeça é que nem celular de pobre (i.e.: tem pouca memória), daí eu não lembro de voltar naquelas perguntas legais dois dias depois para deixar um presentinho.

Eu vi que toda pergunta tem *feed*, mas além de fazer eras que eu não escuto falar de RSS e agregador, eu acho que as perguntas não emitem notificação de que chegou a hora de poder recompensar.

P.s.: eu vi essa pergunta: [É possível receber notificações de perguntas específicas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1386/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-receber-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-perguntas-espec%C3%ADficas) É claro que é, mas o que eu peço aqui é um "tchã" a mais do que isso.